# Can a char array be used with any data type?

Tags: c, arrays, types, c11

The `malloc()` function returns a pointer of type `void*`. It allocates memory in bytes according to the `size_t` value passed as argument to it. The resulting allocation is raw bytes which can be used with any data type in C(without casting).

Can an array with type `char` declared within a function that returns `void *`, be used with any data type like the resulting allocation of `malloc`?

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *Stat_Mem();

int main(void)
{
    //size : 10 * sizeof(int)
    int buf[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    int *p = Stat_Mem();

    memcpy(p, buf, sizeof(buf));

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        printf("%d ", p[n]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

void *Stat_Mem()
{
    static char Array[128];
    return Array;
}
```

Comment: No. An array like this `char array[n];` *has* a declared type: Array of char. Accessing it through an lvalue of a type other than `char` (or another character type) is undefined. `[m/c/re]alloc()` are special in that they allocate memory *without* a declared type.

Comment: `char*` can alias any type. But not vice versa. Basically you are trying to access `char*` as `int*` here, which is a violation of this rule.

Comment: @machine_1  It is not valid that the static character array is aligned appropriately for the casted type.

Comment: You can return any pointer as `void *`. But you must only dereference it with its effective type!

Comment: @EOF then how is the malloc array be used with all the data types??

Comment: Do we have the *strict aliasing* topic in the [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) yet?

Comment: @EOF are you saying reinterpret_cast<> is undefined?

Comment: @machine_1: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5 Expressions 6 The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the
object, if any. 87) If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the
effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify
the stored value.*

Comment: @DavidThomas: `reinterpret_cast<>` is not part of C.

Comment: @EOF I stand corrected.

Comment: @EOF Just for clarification of the quote. Once you have filled the allocated memory with some struct data, it's effective type becomes this struct type. Right?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Until you write to the memory through a different type, yes.

Comment: It is legal to xplicitly cast a pointer to a different type. EOF asserted that this kind of reinterpretation was undefined.  The statement needs to include alignment to be accurate. If the programmer assures proper alignment it is not undefined.

Comment: @EOF That's an interesting point. Not sure I understand it fully. Can I allocate some memory, cast the pointer to `T1*`, fill it with `T1` data and then *cast* it back to `void*`, then to `T2*` and write `T2` there?

Comment: @DavidThomas I assert that *accessing* an array of `char` though an lvalue of type `int`, as the OP's question does, is undefined. C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5 Expressions 7 An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
the following types: 88)
— a type compatible with the effective type of the object,[...]
— a character type.*

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, you can.

Comment: @EOF I contribute " If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access "  per 6.5.6.  `char a[16]; int foo = *(int *)(void *)a;` Furthermore, `*(int*)(void*)a = 10;`  E.g. This is precisely how big/little endian conversions are performed.

Comment: @DavidThomas Did you read my very first comment on this question?

Comment: The OP has erased the type by the return value of Stat_mem.  This makes it an object of no declared type.

Comment: But it *is* declared. Right there, in the code.

Comment: @DavidThomas: What? No. Casting a pointer does not change the declared type of the object it points to.

Comment: @EOF Are you on C docs?

Comment: @2501 Pardon me? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @EOF Are you on documentation beta?

Comment: @2501: I've looked into it and requested a topic, but haven't really contributed yet. Why?

Comment: @EOF I have posted some docs for strict aliasing in C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declared type of the static object `Array` is `char`. The effective type of this object is it's declared type. The effective type of a static object cannot be changed, thus for the remainder of the program the effective type of `Array` is `char`.

If you try to access the value of an object with a type that is not compatible with, or not on this list<sup>1</sup>, the behavior is undefined.

Your code tries to access the stored value of `Array` using the type `int`. This type is not compatible with the type `char` and is not on the list of exceptions, so the behavior is undefined when you read the array using the `int` pointer `p`:

```
printf("%d ", p[n]);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO:IEC 9899:201X 6.5 Expressions 7 )
An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
 expression that has one of the following types:
 — a type
 compatible with the effective type of the object,
 — a qualified
 version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
 — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
 effective type of the object,
 — a type that is the signed or unsigned
 type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the
 object,
— an aggregate or union type that includes one of the
 aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a
 member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
— a character type.

Comment: Is there *anything* legal can be done with dereferencing `p` after `memcpy(p, buf, sizeof(buf));` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Only if you're using allocated storage duration.

Comment: Not sure I understand this sentence.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Look up *storage duration* in the Standard.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you think of any way in which code might take advantage of c11's new _Alignas qualifier without relying upon behaviors where the Standard imposes no requirements?

Comment: @Seb: Compilers don't need permission to align things in whatever fashion they would consider optimal; some ABIs might imply that structures should be laid out in less-than-optimal fashion, but the Standard doesn't consider such issues.  By far the most common scenario where aligning something more coarsely than would be required for its own type would be useful occurs with implementations that allow arrays of static or automatic duration to be used for type-agnostic data storage--something any platform should be able to support with zero loss of efficiency.

Comment: @supercat Indeed they don't. You'd be able to cite that with a quotation if only you knew where in the standard to look ;) You're aware that the most common *platform*s used all carry a cost when data is misaligned, right? It seems like you're confused... Have you ever designed a 32-bit bus that aligns to non-32-bit-aligned regions without cost before? You would be paying much more for such a mainboard...

Comment: @Seb: No object can *require* alignment coarser than its size, but objects may nonetheless *benefit* from such alignment.  For example, an implementation might be faster to load 16-bit values which are known to be 32-bit aligned than those which are not.  In the absence of any ABI constraints, I'm not sure what generally-useful optimizations an implementation would be allowed to perform given _Alignas which it would not be able to perform in the absence of such a directive.  If _Alignas was applicable to pointer-target types, I could see some very useful optimization opportunities there, ...

Comment: ...but that would require that the Standard include rules about pointer compatibility which it presently lacks (e.g. would a `void _Alignas(int) *foo` be required to have the same representation as a `void *foo` even in platforms where an `int*` would be smaller than a `char*`?).  Is the qualifier valid for pointers?  If not, what optimizations would it facilitate?

Comment: @supercat How would you expect a compiler to know how to optimise for a platform when it hasn't been told how? Those are the situations this would be useful for. Indeed, you could use a union instead. On a vaguely related note, you could use casting and pointer arithmetic to determine the size of an object, too, but most people are fine and dandy with `sizeof`...

Comment: @Seb: I suppose it's possible that cache-line alignment might be more important for some objects than others, and _Alignof might help with that, but being able to declare a pool of buffers that can be used to hold things of any type whose alignment is no coarser than a particular type seems like it would be far more useful on implementations that don't interpret aliasing rules as preventing that.

Comment: @Seb supercat Please use chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot use an arbitrary byte array for an arbitrary type because of possible alignment problems. The standard says in 6.3.2.3 Conversions/Pointers (emphasize mine):

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different
>   object or incomplete type. **If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the
>   pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined**. Otherwise, when converted back again, the
>   result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

As a char as the smallest alignment requirement, you cannot make sure that your char array will be correctly aligned for any other type. That is why malloc guarantees that a buffer obtained by malloc (even if it is a `void *`) has the largest possible alignement requirement to be able to accept any other type.

---

I think that

```
union {
    char buf[128];
    long long i;
    void * p;
    long double f;
};
```

should have correct alignment for any type as it is compatible with largest basic types (as defined in 6.2.5 Types). I am pretty sure that it will work for all common implementations (gcc, clang, msvc, ...) but unfortunately I could not find any confirmation that the standard allows it. Essentially because of the strict aliasing rule as defined in 6.5 Expression §7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>     object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>     effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>     members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

So IMHO there is not portable and standard conformant way to build a custom *allocator* not using `malloc`.

Comment: The alignment is not relevant here. This is because this would still be undefined if the alignment were the same. The problem is effective type of the static char array, which cannot be changed to int. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38510909/4082723

Comment: @2501: That link goes to a deleted answer, not everyone can see it.

Comment: @2501: Alignment is something visible on ARM architectures: you get errors if you do not respect it, even non language lawyers can understand it. I know that converting a pointer to one type to a pointer to another type gives a pointer that you can only convert back to the original type. But it is harder to make it *real*.

Comment: The part about the `union` in the end is questionable. The only seemingly related thing I find in the standard is C11 draft standard n1570 *6.2.5 Types 28 A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. [...] All pointers to structure [and respecively] union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.* , but this is talking about the alignment *of the pointer itself*, not of the type *pointed to*.

Comment: I agree, alignment is important, but since C allows for alignment to be the same for all types, it ultimately comes down to strict aliasing.

Comment: @EOF: After reading your comment, I agree with you: I had misunderstood paragraph 6.2.5

Answer (score -1):

If one reads the rationale of the C89 Standard, the only reason that the type- aliasing rules exist is to avoid requiring compilers to make "worst-case aliasing assumptions".  The given example was:

```
    int a;
    void f( double * b )
    {
        a = 1;
        *b = 2.0;
        g(a);
    }
```

If program creates a "char" array within a union containing something whose alignment would be suitable for any type, takes the address thereof, and never accesses the storage of that structure except through the resulting pointer, there should be no reason why aliasing rules should cause any difficulty.

It's worthwhile to note that the authors of the Standard recognized that an implementation could be simultaneously compliant but useless; see the rationale for C89 2.2.4.1:

> While a deficient implementation could probably contrive a program that meets this requirement, yet still succeed in being useless, the Committee felt that such ingenuity would probably require more work than making something useful.  The sense of the Committee is that implementors should not construe the translation limits as the values of hard-wired parameters, but rather as a set of criteria by which an implementation will be judged.

While that particular statement is made with regard to implementation limits, the only way to interpret the C89 as being even remotely compatible with the C dialects that preceded it is to regard it as applying more broadly as well: the Standard doesn't try to exhaustively specify everything that a program should be able to do, but relies upon compiler writers' exercising some common sense.

Use of a character-type array as a backing store of any type, assuming one ensures alignment issues are taken care of, shouldn't cause any problems with a non-obtusely written compiler.  The Standard didn't mandate that compiler writers allow such things because they saw no reason to expect them to do otherwise.  Unfortunately, they failed to foresee the path the language would take in the 21st Century.

Comment: That citation is entirely out of context. The problem with the implementation limits is not even remotely related to accessing objects though lvalues of types other than the effective type of the object.

Comment: @EOF: It proves that the authors of the Standard did intend to fully describe the behavior of a *quality* C implementation, and recognized that a C implementation could simultaneously be fully compliant and yet of such poor quality to be useless.  The fact that a compliant C compiler is allowed to ignore cases in which aliasing is obvious does not mean that a C compiler which does so should not be considered grossly inferior to one that recognizes such aliasing.

Comment: s/did intend/didn't intend/