# Does this type aliasing using union invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

For example,

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

struct ipv4addr {
  union {
    std::uint32_t value;
    std::uint8_t parts[4];
  };
};

int main() {
  ipv4addr addr;
  addr.value = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(-1);
  std::printf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu",
    addr.parts[0], addr.parts[1], addr.parts[2], addr.parts[3]);
}
```

Per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union),

> The details of that allocation are implementation-defined, and it's
>   undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't
>   most recently written.

So looks like the code invokes undefined behavior. But the page also says

> If two union members are standard-layout types, it's well-defined to
>   examine their common subsequence on any compiler.

I don't quite understand this. Does it make the code behavior well-defined?

Also note cppref's description on [type aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an
>   object of type `DynamicType` through a glvalue of type `AliasedType`, the
>   behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> - [...]
> - `AliasedType` is `std::byte`, `char`, or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of
>     bytes.

I guess this applies to `std::uint8_t` as well. No?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior) answer yours?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762186/unions-aliasing-and-type-punning-in-practice-what-works-and-what-does-not/54763849#54763849) may be informative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior)

Comment: I admit to having no freaking clue what happens to a `uint8` on a system where a byte is 16 bits. Time for some Standard-diving.

Comment: Ah ha! It's optional! In other words it byte isn't 8 bits, this probably won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common initial subsequence has a ridiculously specific definition.  `int` and `struct foo{int x;}` do **not** have a common initial subsequence.

`struct foo{int x;}` and `struct bar{int y;}` do have a common initial subsequence.

Reading memory through an unrelated type is not the same as reading from a union alternative.  That text doesn't do anything there.

You can do `(std::unit8_t const*)&addr.value` and treat it as a 4 byte array, assuming your platform has `unit8_t`.  The byte values you get are implementation defined.

You cannot, under the standard, read from  `parts[i]` however (when value exists).

Compilers are free to specify behaviour when the standard states it is undefined under the standard, except during a compile time `constexpr` evaluation.

Comment: Members of a union are pointer-interconvertible, do you not get the same lvalue from the cast compared to accessing directly?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the contents of a union member that was not most-recently assigned is indeed undefined behavior. However, most all compilers I've used have non-standard extensions to allow it.

Technically if you want this to be safe with no chance for failure you should store the ip as `int32_t` and reinterpret via `reinterpret_cast` to read the individual bytes, like so:

```
int32_t ip = 185734;
int8_t *ip_bytes = reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(&ip).

ip_bytes[etc]...
```

However, you should keep in mind the endianness of your platform will impact the byte ordering for any 32-bit read/write. Therefore it may be safer to scrap the `int32_t` idea entirely and just use an array of bytes. It all depends on what you need and/or whatever any library you might be using requires.

Comment: Guess I will stick to `std::uint32_t`, but get `parts` by 256 modulo (`/ 256` and `% 256` consecutively). This also removes dependency on endianness.

Comment: @Lingxi Either that or bitwise, whichever is clearer. Compiler will optimize both the same way regardless. And I'd recommend making a wrapper type for it just for readability/reliability.

Answer (score -2):

That's well defined to do exactly what fwrite followed by four get calls to read it back does. The actual result is machine dependent. "Get me the bytes for this uint32" in whatever storage mode the CPU prefers.