# C++ Union Member Access And Undefined Behaviour

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, unions

I am currently working on a project in which I am provided the following
structre. My work is C++ but the project uses both C and C++. The same structure
definition is used by both C and C++.

```
typedef struct PacketHeader {
    //Byte 0
    uint8_t  bRes                           :4;
    uint8_t  bEmpty                         :1;
    uint8_t  bWait                          :1;
    uint8_t  bErr                           :1;
    uint8_t  bEnable                        :1;
    //Byte 1
    uint8_t  bInst                          :4;
    uint8_t  bCount                         :3;
    uint8_t  bRres                          :1;
    //Bytes 2, 3
    union {
        uint16_t wId;    /* Needed for Endian swapping */
        struct{
            uint16_t wMake                  :4;
            uint16_t wMod                   :12;
        };
    };
} PacketHeader;
```

Depending on how instances of the structure are used, the required endianness of
the structure can be big or little endian. As the first two bytes of the
structure are each single bytes, these don't need altering when the endianness
changes.
Bytes 2 and 3, stored as a single `uint16_t`, are the only bytes which we need to
swap to acheive the desired endianness. To acheive the endianness swap, we have
been performing the following:

```
//Returns a constructed instance of PacketHeader with relevant fields set and the provided counter value
PacketHeader myHeader = mmt::BuildPacketHeader(count);

uint16_t packetIdFlipped;
//Swap positions of byte 2 and 3
packetIdFlipped = myHeader.wId << 8;
packetIdFlipped |= (uint16_t)myHeader.wId >> 8;

myHeader.wId = packetIdFlipped;
```

The function `BuildPacketHeader(uint8_t)` assigns values to the members `wMake` and
`wMod` explicitly, and **does not** write to the member `wId`. My question is regarding
the safety of reading from the member `wId` inside the returned instance of the
structure.

Questions such as
[Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior),
[Purpose of Unions in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c),
and [Section 10.4 of the draft standard I have](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4778.pdf) each mention the undefined behaviour arising from accessing an inactive member of a union in C++.

Paragraph 1 in Section 10.4 of the linked draft also contains the following note, though I'm not sure I understand all the terminology used:

> [Note: One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence (10.3), and if a non-static datamember of an object of this standard-layout union type is active and is one of the standard-layout structs, itis permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of the standard-layout struct members; see 10.3.— end note]

Is reading `myHeader.wId` in the line `packetIdFlipped = myHeader.wId << 8` undefined behaviour?

Is the unnamed struct the active member as it was the last member written to in the function call?

Or does the note mean it is safe to access the `wId` member, as it and the struct share a common type? (and is this what is meant by *common initial sequence*?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anonymous structs are ill-formed in C++. I.e. this: `struct{
            /* members */
        };`

Comment: @eerorika Thank you - I hadn't even realised that. Looking into it led me a comment _Similar to union, an unnamed member of a struct whose type is a struct without name is known as anonymous struct. Every member of an anonymous struct is considered to be a member of the enclosing struct or union. This applies recursively if the enclosing struct or union is also anonymous_ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct). Does this mean that the code above actually _is not_ UB as each member of the inner struct and union are considered members of `struct PacketHeader`?

Comment: It is UB. The union being anonymous doesn't change anything.

Comment: Don't seem to find the edit comment button but, on closer reading, I think that link was referring to C anyhow. 

Many thanks, once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is reading `myHeader.wId` in the line `packetIdFlipped = myHeader.wId << 8` undefined behaviour?

Yes.  You assigned to `wMake` and `wMod` making the unamed struct the active member so `wId` is the inactive member and you are not allowed to read from it without setting a value to it.

> and is this what is meant by *common initial sequence*?

The [common initial sequence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem-22) is when two [standard layout types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) share the same members in the same order.  In

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct bar
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

`a` and `b` are of the same type in `foo` and `bar` so they are the common initial sequence of them.  If you put objects of `foo` and `bar` in a union it would be safe to read `a` or `b` from wither object after it is set in one of them.

This is not your case though since `wId` isn't a standard layout type struct.

Comment: Would wrapping `wId` in a `struct ID{ ... }` suffice to provide a _standard layout type_? And, if so, would it share a _common initial sequence_ with the following, anonymous (in the provided example - will be changed now that eerorika pointed out it is ill defined) struct, as each consist of a `uint16_t` initial member? Or does the fact that the latter struct's member is a bit-field mean they are not common types?

Comment: I should read more thoroughly before asking more questions, my apologies. The links you posted linked to another page, clarifying _and if they are bit-fields, they have the same width_.

Comment: @cprlkleg That still would not be legal.  Both structs would have to have a bit field for it to be legal, as you found out.

Answer (score 4):

> The function BuildPacketHeader(uint8_t) assigns values to the members
>   wMake and wMod explicitly, and does not write to the member wId. My
>   question is regarding the safety of reading from the member wId inside
>   the returned instance of the structure.

Yes, it's UB. It does not mean it's not working, just that it may not work. You can use memcpy inside BuildPacketHeader to avoid that (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789928/whats-a-proper-way-of-type-punning-a-float-to-an-int-and-vice-versa/17790026#17790026) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762186/unions-aliasing-and-type-punning-in-practice-what-works-and-what-does-not)).

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the memcpy hint. Is this still UB considering the inner union and struct are both anonymous (as pointed out by eerorika), and the following comment _Similar to union, an unnamed member of a struct whose type is a struct without name is known as anonymous struct. Every member of an anonymous struct is considered to be a member of the enclosing struct or union. This applies recursively if the enclosing struct or union is also anonymous._, [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct)
EDIT: The link seems to be referring to C anyhow, my apologies

Answer (score 1):

What the C++ standard kind of says is given two structs A and B and the following untion:

```
union U
{
  A a;
  B b;
};
```

The following is valid code:

```
U u;

A a;
u.a = a;
a = u.a;

B b;
u.b = b;
b = u.b;
```

You read and write the same type. This is obviously correct code.

But the problem comes when you have the following code:

```
A a;
B b;
u.a = a;
b = u.b;
```

What do we know about A and B? First in the union they share the same memory space. Now the C++ standard has plainly declared it as undefined behavior.

But that does not mean it's fully out of the window. C99 comes into play, since it is the normative base and there are weak guarantees about unions. That is if the union member have the same memory layout they are compatible and each structs first memory address is the same. So if you can ensure that your structs / union members are all padded in the correct way the operation is safe, even if C++ says it's undefined.

Finally from a pragmatic standpoint, if you don't mess with padding and get the standard layout, the compiler will generally do the right thing, since that is a quite old usage pattern in C and breaking this will break LOTS of code.