# Portability of using union for conversion

Tags: c, unions

I want to represent a 32-bit number using RGBA values, is it portable to generate the values for said number using a union? Consider this C code;

```
union pixel {
    uint32_t value;
    uint8_t RGBA[4];
};
```

This compiles fine, and id like to use it instead of a bunch of functions. But is it safe?

Comment: How do you plan to use the union, and what results do you hope to achieve?

Comment: If you assign a value such as 0x01234567 to `value`, the number in `RGBA[0]` will be different depending on whether the platform is big-endian (0x01) or little-endian (0x67).  Therefore, it is not portable across platforms with different endianness.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is endianness the only issue? If so, it can always be accounted for.

Comment: @QuestionLimitGoBrrrrr, I think it's also unspecified behavior--allowed only by a gcc extension, but I can't find the reference in the gcc manual at the moment. I added some more links to the bottom of my answer though for you to go dig down.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: In C, reading a union other than the last one written reinterprets the bytes in the new type; it is not unspecified or undefined. In C++, the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, `In C, reading a union other than the last one written reinterprets the bytes in the new type`. Indeed, it does do this. I've done this in both C and C++ with the gcc compiler and saw no difference. But, that's due to a gcc extension, apparently, making it so. But, the C standard states it is "unspecified behavior." See the Annex J "Portability Issues" screenshot and quote for the C standard in my answer.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Annex J is non-normative. In my other comment, I cited normative text. Additionally, the text you highlight is inapplicable. The bytes of a four-byte integer and a four-byte array overlap exactly; none are left unspecified in this case.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, can you help me find the standard? Do I need to go buy it? I don't have a copy of a final standard. Or, can you find the words in [the one I link to](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) has information about locating the C standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using Unions for "type punning" is fine in C, and fine in gcc's C++ as well (as a gcc [g++] extension). But, "type punning" via unions has hardware architecture *endianness considerations*.

This is called ["type punning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning), and it is not *directly portable* due to endianness considerations. However, otherwise, doing it is just fine. The C standards have NOT been great about making it clear this is just fine, but apparently it is. Read these answers and sources:

1. [Is type-punning through a union unspecified in C99, and has it become specified in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified/11640603#11640603)
2. [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning/25672839#25672839)
3. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type%2Dpunning - type punning is allowed in gcc C and C++

Additionally, the C18 draft, [N2176 ISO/IEC 9899:2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) states in section "6.5.2.3 Structure and union members", the following in footnote 97:

> 97. If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the
>     object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new
>     type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called “type punning”). This might be a trap representation.

See it in this screenshot here:

[image]

So, having

```c
typedef union my_union_u
{
    uint32_t value;
    /// A byte array large enough to hold the largest of any value in the union.
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(uint32_t)];
} my_union_t;
```

as a means of translating `value` into `bytes` is just fine in C. In C++ it works as a GNU gcc extension (but not as part of the C++ standard). [See @Christoph's explanation in his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning/25672839#25672839):

> GNU extensions to standard C++ (and to C90) [do explicitly allow type-punning with unions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type%2Dpunning). Other compilers that don't support GNU extensions may also support union type-punning, but it's not part of the base language standard.

---

**Download the code:** *you can download and run all the code below from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: ["type_punning.c"](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/type_punning.c). gcc build and run commands for both C *and* C++ are found in the comments at the very top of the file.*

---

So, you can do something like this to read the individual bytes out of the `uint32_t value`:

**TECHNIQUE 1: union-based type punning (this *is* "type punning"):**

*This is what "type punning" means:* writing one type into a union and then reading out another type, thereby using the union to perform type "conversion".

```c
my_union_t u;

// write to uint32_t value
u.value = 1234;

// read individual bytes from uint32_t value
printf("1st byte = 0x%02X\n", (u.bytes)[0]);
printf("2nd byte = 0x%02X\n", (u.bytes)[1]);
printf("3rd byte = 0x%02X\n", (u.bytes)[2]);
printf("4th byte = 0x%02X\n", (u.bytes)[3]);
```

Sample output:

1. On a *little-endian* architecture:

   > ```
   > 1st byte = 0xD2
   > 2nd byte = 0x04
   > 3rd byte = 0x00
   > 4th byte = 0x00
   > ```
2. On a *big-endian* architecture:

   > ```
   > 1st byte = 0x00
   > 2nd byte = 0x00
   > 3rd byte = 0x04
   > 4th byte = 0xD2
   > ```

### You can use raw pointers to obtain bytes from variables too, but this technique also has hardware architecture endianness issues.

This could be done withOUT a union if you wanted by using raw pointers too, like this:

**TECHNIQUE 2: reading through raw pointers (this is *not* "type punning"):**

```c
uint32_t value = 1234;
uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)&value;

// read individual bytes from uint32_t value
printf("1st byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[0]);
printf("2nd byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[1]);
printf("3rd byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[2]);
printf("4th byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[3]);
```

Sample output:

1. On a *little-endian* architecture:

   > ```
   > 1st byte = 0xD2
   > 2nd byte = 0x04
   > 3rd byte = 0x00
   > 4th byte = 0x00
   > ```
2. On a *big-endian* architecture:

   > ```
   > 1st byte = 0x00
   > 2nd byte = 0x00
   > 3rd byte = 0x04
   > 4th byte = 0xD2
   > ```

### You can use bitmasks and bit-shifting to avoid hardware architecture endianness portability issues.

To avoid endianness issues which exist with both the *union type punning* and *raw pointer* approaches above, you can use something like the following instead. This avoids endianness differences between hardware architectures:

**TECHNIQUE 3.1: use bit-masks and bit shifting (this is *not* "type punning"):**

```c
uint32_t value = 1234;

uint8_t byte0 = (value >> 0)  & 0xff;
uint8_t byte1 = (value >> 8)  & 0xff;
uint8_t byte2 = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
uint8_t byte3 = (value >> 24) & 0xff;

printf("1st byte = 0x%02X\n", byte0);
printf("2nd byte = 0x%02X\n", byte1);
printf("3rd byte = 0x%02X\n", byte2);
printf("4th byte = 0x%02X\n", byte3);
```

Sample output (the above technique is endianness-independent!):

1. On a *all* architectures: both *big-endian* AND *little-endian*:

   > ```
   > 1st byte = 0xD2
   > 2nd byte = 0x04
   > 3rd byte = 0x00
   > 4th byte = 0x00
   > ```

OR:

**TECHNIQUE 3.2: use a convenience macro to do bit-masks and bit shifting:**

```c
#define BYTE(value, byte_num) ((uint8_t)(((value) >> (8*(byte_num))) & 0xff))

uint32_t value = 1234;

uint8_t byte0 = BYTE(value, 0);
uint8_t byte1 = BYTE(value, 1);
uint8_t byte2 = BYTE(value, 2);
uint8_t byte3 = BYTE(value, 3);

// OR

uint8_t bytes[] = {
    BYTE(value, 0), 
    BYTE(value, 1), 
    BYTE(value, 2), 
    BYTE(value, 3), 
};

printf("1st byte = 0x%02X\n", byte0);
printf("2nd byte = 0x%02X\n", byte1);
printf("3rd byte = 0x%02X\n", byte2);
printf("4th byte = 0x%02X\n", byte3);
printf("---------------\n");
printf("1st byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[0]);
printf("2nd byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[1]);
printf("3rd byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[2]);
printf("4th byte = 0x%02X\n", bytes[3]);
```

Sample output (the above technique is endianness-independent!):

1. On a *all* architectures: both *big-endian* AND *little-endian*:

   > ```
   > 1st byte = 0xD2
   > 2nd byte = 0x04
   > 3rd byte = 0x00
   > 4th byte = 0x00
   > ---------------
   > 1st byte = 0xD2
   > 2nd byte = 0x04
   > 3rd byte = 0x00
   > 4th byte = 0x00
   > ```

Otherwise, `(my_pixel.RGBA)[0]`, or `(u.bytes)[0]`, might be equal to `byte0` (as I've defined it above) if the architecture is *Little-endian*, or equal to `byte3` if the architecture is *Big-endian*.

See this endianness graphic below: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness. Notice that In big-endian, the *most-significant-**byte*** of any given variable is stored first (meaning: in lower addresses) in memory, but in little-endian it is the *least-significant-**byte*** that is stored first (in lower addresses) in memory. Also remember that endianness describes **byte** order, NOT **bit** order (bit order within a byte has nothing to do with endianness), and that each byte is 2 hex characters, or "nibbles", where a nibble is 4 bits.

[image]

According to the Wikipedia article above, *networking protocols* usually use *big-endian* byte order, whereas *most processors (x86, most ARM, etc.)*, usually are *little-endian* (emphasis added):

> **Big-endianness** is the dominant ordering in **networking protocols**, such as in the internet protocol suite, where it is referred to as network order, *transmitting the most significant byte first*. Conversely, **little-endianness** is the dominant ordering for **processor architectures (x86, most ARM implementations, base RISC-V implementations) and their associated memory**.

---

### More notes regarding whether or not "type punning" is supported by the standard

According to [Wikipedia's "Type punning" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning), writing to union member `value` but reading from `RGBA[4]` is "unspecified behavior". However, [@Eric Postpischil points out in his comment below this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206482/portability-of-using-union-for-conversion/67206563?noredirect=1#comment118803979_67206563) that Wikipedia is wrong. The other references at the top of this answer also don't align with the Wikipedia answer as it is written now.

[Eric Postpischil's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206482/portability-of-using-union-for-conversion/67206563?noredirect=1#comment118803979_67206563), which I now understand and agree with, states (emphasis added):

> The quoted text, about bytes corresponding to union members other than the last one stored, does not apply to this situation. It applies to a case where, for example, **a two-byte `short` member is written and a four-byte `int` member is read. The extra two bytes are unspecified. This gives a C implementation license to implement the store to the `short` as a two-byte store (leaving the remaining bytes of the union unchanged) or a four-byte store (perhaps because it is efficient for the processor).** In the case at hand, we have a four-byte `uint32_t` member and a four-byte `uint8_t [4]` member.

Wikipedia claims (as of 22 Apr. 2021):

For union:

```c
union {
    unsigned int ui;
    float d;
} my_union = { .d = x };
```

> Accessing `my_union.ui` after initializing the other member, `my_union.d`, is still a form of type-punning [[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#cite_note-4) in C and the result is [unspecified behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) [[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#cite_note-5) (and [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C++ [[6]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#cite_note-6)).

From [reference [5] above](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf): "Unspecified Behavior" includes:

> The values of bytes that correspond to union members other than the one last stored into (6.2.6.1).

<s>This means that if you *store data into one member of a union*, but *read it from another*, which is *exactly what you're wanting to use that union for*, it is "unspecified behavior" per the C standard.</s>

[image]

<s>I think gcc allows type punning (writing into one member of a union, but reading from another member in the union, as a form of "translation") as a "gcc extension", but the C and C++ standards, if using `-Wpedantic` in your build flags, otherwise prohibit it.</s>

### See also:

1. Download and run all of the above code from my repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/type_punning.c
2. [Unions, aliasing and type-punning in practice: what works and what does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762186/unions-aliasing-and-type-punning-in-practice-what-works-and-what-does-not)
3. [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning)
4. [my repo] I added `READ_BYTE()` as a macro to my [**utilities.h**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/utilities.h#L120) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.
5. [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)
6. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17263328

   1. [Is type-punning through a union unspecified in C99, and has it become specified in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639947/is-type-punning-through-a-union-unspecified-in-c99-and-has-it-become-specified) <== SEE HERE ESPECIALLY. APPARENTLY THE C STANDARD HASN'T BEEN GOOD ABOUT BEING SUPER CLEAR ABOUT THIS.
7. More of my answers:

   1. [Answer 1/3: use a union and a packed struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984037/4561887).
   2. [Answer 2/3: convert a struct to an array of bytes via manual bit-shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984464/4561887).
   3. [Answer 3/3: use a packed struct and a raw uint8_t pointer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984614/4561887).

Comment: Wikipedia is not a great reference for C language behaviour, it would be better to quote direcly the sources that wikipedia references .  I disagree that it is unspecified behaviour in C, it is implementation-defined (based on the system endianness and sizes of types)

Comment: @M.M, yeah, this would require further research on my end. For now though I'll let it rest.

Comment: @M.M, note: if you see something wrong on Wikipedia, and you've done the detailed research to be absolutely sure, please just fix it. That's what it's there for: a wiki, for anyone to edit. I do the same. I edit and add to https://cppreference.com (also a wiki) and [Wikipedia.org](https://www.wikipedia.org/) regularly.

Comment: I spend enough time on internet arguments, don't really want to deal with competing edits from someone with a different view :)  The solution would be to link to a canonical SO question anyway I would think

Comment: @GabrielStaples: In C, reading a union other than the last one written reinterprets the bytes in the new type, per C 2018 6.5.2.3 3 and note 99. It is not unspecified or undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, since I'm using the [latest draft copy of that standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf), as found under the "C17/C18" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83763/4561887), because I don't want to pay for a paid copy for the sake of argument alone, can you please provide the exact quote instead of the section numbers, so I can find it in the draft version too? A highlighted screenshot would also suffice. I'm trying to get my answer "upvotable" and correct here.

Comment: Please note that this non-wayback-machine link to [N2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf) seems valid. Also, in a previous draft ([N1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)), the note mentioned by E.Postpischil is [97](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p5).

Comment: @GabrielStaples: 6.5.2.3 3 in the official version is 6.5.2.3 in the draft you link to, and note 99 is note 97.

Comment: The quoted text, about bytes corresponding to union members other than the last one stored, does not apply to this situation. It applies to a case where, for example, a two-byte `short` member is written and a four-byte `int` member is read. The extra two bytes are unspecified. This gives a C implementation license to implement the store to the `short` as a two-byte store (leaving the remaining bytes of the union unchanged) or a four-byte store (perhaps because it is efficient for the processor). In the case at hand, we have a four-byte `uint32_t` member and a four-byte `uint8_t [4]` member.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, after further research, I agree with you. I've updated my answer as a result. Thank you for your latest comment with detailed explanation.