# How to convert a struct variable to uint8_t array in C

Tags: c

I have a struct variable of struct:

```
typedef struct message_t
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;   
    uint8_t ns;  
    uint16_t lon;  
    uint8_t ew;  
} message;

message msg;
msg.time = 0x1234;
msg.lat = 0x2122;
msg.ns = 'n';
msg.lon = 0x2234;
msg.ew = 'e';

uint8_t msg_arr[8];
```

How to convert `msg` to uint8_t array `msg_arr[8]`?

By using memcpy to convert the data,

```
memcpy(msg_arr, &msg, sizeof(msg_arr));
for(int i=0; i < 8; i++){
  printf("msg[%d]: %d \n", i, msg_arr[i]);
}
```

I get the output:

```
msg[0]: 52 
msg[1]: 18 
msg[2]: 34 
msg[3]: 33 
msg[4]: 110 
msg[5]: 0 
msg[6]: 52 
msg[7]: 34
```

It seems something wrong with using memcpy. for example, `msg[5], msg[6] and msg[7]` are not correct.

Comment: What about `memcpy(msg_arr, &msg, sizeof(message));`? Be careful to ensure `msg_arr` is at least `sizeof(message)` bytes. The size of a struct can be bigger than the sum of the size of its elements due to padding.

Comment: You can `memcpy(msg_arr, &msg, sizeof(msg_arr))`, however, beware that memory padding maybe be added in structs to satisfy the [Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). For receiving the message just copy it in reverse `memcpy(&msg, msg_arr, sizeof(msg_arr))`.

Comment: @JardelLucca (your thinking right but you mixed your `memset()` with your `memcpy()`)

Comment: @David C. Rankin, indeed... Thanks for the correction!

Comment: If the idea is to send data in byte units, probably there's no need for copying data. Maybe also there's no need to cast the struct to `uint8_t *`. @lei lei, what are you planing to do with `msg_arr`?

Comment: thanks guys. I need to put msg_arr into a function which requests uint8_t array as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer 1/3: use a union and a packed struct

See also my much longer answer here: [Portability of using union for conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206482/portability-of-using-union-for-conversion/67206563#67206563)

You can do the conversion to a byte array using a union. Be sure to pack the struct to remove padding bytes.

```c
typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) message_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_t;

typedef union message_converter_u
{
    message_t message;
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(message_t)];
} message_converter_t;
```

Now do the conversion through the `message_converter_t` union:

```c
message_t message =
{
    .time = 0x1234,
    .lat = 0x2122,
    .ns = 'n',  // 0x6E
    .lon = 0x1834,
    .ew = 'e', // 0x65
};

message_converter_t converter;
converter.message = message;
```

That's it!

`converter.bytes` is now magically a `uint8_t` array with 8 elements containing all the bytes of the struct.

It has endianness considerations, however!

*Note: copying `message` into `converter.message` above is unnecessarily inefficient, since it's an unnecessary byte-for-byte copy of the whole `message` struct. A more-efficient way is to simply construct the union type alone and populate the struct data inside the union directly. See "**struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union_more_efficient.c**" below for that demo.*

Here is some sample print code to print all the bytes:

```c
// Print the bytes
printf("bytes = [");
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(converter.bytes); i++)
{
    printf("0x%02X", converter.bytes[i]);
    if (i < sizeof(converter.bytes) - 1)
    {
        printf(", ");
    }
}
printf("]\n");
```

and the output on a 64-bit **little-endian** x86-architecture Linux machine:

> ```
> bytes = [0x34, 0x12, 0x22, 0x21, 0x6E, 0x34, 0x18, 0x65]
> ```

Notice that due to my machine being **little-endian**, the least-significant-byte `0x34` comes first in the `time` variable of `0x1234`. So, you get `0x34` and then `0x12`. This happens with all of the multi-byte variables. To remove endianness considerations across hardware architectures, you'd have to move to a bit-shifting approach instead of using a union--see my link above for examples and more details, and also see [my Answer 2/3 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984464/4561887).

---

### Full, runnable example

[struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union.c): <-- download it as part of my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo

```c
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

typedef struct message_unpacked_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_unpacked_t;

typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) message_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_t;

typedef union message_converter_u
{
    message_t message;
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(message_t)];
} message_converter_t;

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("This is the start of `main()`.\n");

    // demonstrate that packing the struct matters
    printf("sizeof(message_unpacked_t) = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(message_unpacked_t)); // 10 bytes due to padding
    printf("sizeof(message_t) = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(message_t)); // 8 bytes

    message_t message =
    {
        .time = 0x1234,
        .lat = 0x2122,
        .ns = 'n',  // 0x6E
        .lon = 0x1834,
        .ew = 'e', // 0x65
    };

    message_converter_t converter;
    // Note: copying `message` into `converter.message` here is unnecessarily inefficient. A
    // more-efficient way is to simply construct the union type alone and populate the struct
    // data inside the union directly. See "struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union_more_efficient.c"
    // for that demo.
    converter.message = message;

    // Print the bytes
    printf("bytes = [");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(converter.bytes); i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X", converter.bytes[i]);
        if (i < sizeof(converter.bytes) - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Build and run command:

```bash
mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -save-temps=obj struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union.c \
-o bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union && bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union
```

Sample output:

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -save-temps=obj struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union.c \
> >     -o bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union && bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union
> This is the start of `main()`.
> sizeof(message_unpacked_t) = 10 bytes
> sizeof(message_t) = 8 bytes
> bytes = [0x34, 0x12, 0x22, 0x21, 0x6E, 0x34, 0x18, 0x65]
> ```

### More-efficient technique: do NOT copy from a struct to a union! Just use the union alone as your `message_t`!

[struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union_more_efficient.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union_more_efficient.c)

```c
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

typedef struct message_data_unpacked_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_data_unpacked_t;

typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) message_data_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_data_t;

typedef union message_u
{
    message_data_t data;
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(message_data_t)];
} message_t;

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("This is the start of `main()`.\n");

    // demonstrate that packing the struct matters
    printf("sizeof(message_data_unpacked_t) = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(message_data_unpacked_t)); // 10 bytes due to padding
    printf("sizeof(message_data_t) = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(message_data_t)); // 8 bytes

    message_t message =
    {
        .data =
        {
            .time = 0x1234,
            .lat = 0x2122,
            .ns = 'n',  // 0x6E
            .lon = 0x1834,
            .ew = 'e', // 0x65
        },
    };

    // Print the bytes
    printf("bytes = [");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(message.bytes); i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X", message.bytes[i]);
        if (i < sizeof(message.bytes) - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output is the same as before:

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -save-temps=obj struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union_more_efficient.c \
> >     -o bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union_more_efficient && bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_union_more_efficient
> This is the start of `main()`.
> sizeof(message_data_unpacked_t) = 10 bytes
> sizeof(message_data_t) = 8 bytes
> bytes = [0x34, 0x12, 0x22, 0x21, 0x6E, 0x34, 0x18, 0x65]
> ```

### Related

Here is one of my kind of related answers in C++, which I want to remember in case I need to look at it again: [Use a char[4] or char[8] as a constant int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714049/4561887)

<sub>Keywords: c type punning; c struct to byte array conversion; c array to bytes; c serialization; c struct serialization; c object serialization</sub>

Comment: thanks. the output in my side is: bytes = [0x34, 0x12, 0x22, 0x21, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x34, 0x18, 0x65, 0x00] ... why?

Comment: @leilei, you haven't packed your struct, so to keep natural memory alignment an extra byte is padded after each `uint8_t` member to make the next `uint16_t` member have natural 2-byte memory alignment. Notice how I have added `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` to force the struct to be packed to remove these padding bytes.

Comment: I'm doing an unnecessary copy from a `message_t` here to a `message_converter_t`. That's silly of me. Let me update my answer in a bit.

Comment: Done: see the "More-efficient technique" part of my answer I just added to the end.

Comment: I added two other answers with alternative approaches too. Honestly, the raw pointer  ([Answer 3/3: use a packed struct and a raw uint8_t pointer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984614/4561887)) is just as easy as the union, and requires even less code!. And, if you ever need to send serialized data between different systems of different endianness, the endianness-agnostic [Answer 2/3: convert a struct to an array of bytes via manual bit-shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984464/4561887) is better.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer 2/3: convert a struct to an array of bytes via manual bit-shifting

Convert a struct to an array in C via bit shifting, which unlike the union technique, does NOT have
architecture-based endianness concerns or differences which can vary from hardware architecture to
architecture! Rather, the manual bit-shifting *removes* endianness concerns at the expense of
manually copying the bytes from the struct into an array (whereas the union and raw ptr techniques do NOT require copying any bytes)!

This technique being endianness-agnostic makes it better than the other two approaches (union and raw ptr) if you ever need to send serialized data between different systems of different endianness.

[struct_to_array_via_bit_shifting.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/struct_to_array_via_bit_shifting.c):

```c
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

// Read a single byte at index `byte_num` from any multi-byte variable.
#define BYTE(value, byte_num) ((uint8_t)(((value) >> (8*(byte_num))) & 0xff))

// Notice with this technique the struct does NOT need to be packed! This is contrary to the
// union technique.
typedef struct message_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_t;

void message_struct_to_array(const message_t* message, uint8_t* bytes)
{
    bytes[0] = BYTE(message->time, 0);
    bytes[1] = BYTE(message->time, 1);

    bytes[2] = BYTE(message->lat, 0);
    bytes[3] = BYTE(message->lat, 1);

    bytes[4] = BYTE(message->ns, 0);

    bytes[5] = BYTE(message->lon, 0);
    bytes[6] = BYTE(message->lon, 1);

    bytes[7] = BYTE(message->ew, 0);
}

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("Answer 2/3: convert a struct to an array of bytes via manual bit-shifting.\n");

    message_t message =
    {
        .time = 0x1234,
        .lat = 0x2122,
        .ns = 'n',  // 0x6E
        .lon = 0x1834,
        .ew = 'e', // 0x65
    };

    // NB: this is NOT the same thing as `sizeof(message_t)` due to padding bytes which are in the
    // `message_t` struct!
    const size_t MESSAGE_NUM_BYTES = sizeof(message.time) + sizeof(message.lat) +
        sizeof(message.ns) + sizeof(message.lon) + sizeof(message.ew);

    uint8_t bytes[MESSAGE_NUM_BYTES];
    message_struct_to_array(&message, bytes);

    // Print the bytes
    printf("bytes = [");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(bytes); i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X", bytes[i]);
        if (i < sizeof(bytes) - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -save-temps=obj struct_to_array_via_bit_shifting.c \
> >     -o bin/struct_to_array_via_bit_shifting && bin/struct_to_array_via_bit_shifting
> Answer 2/3: convert a struct to an array of bytes via manual bit-shifting.
> bytes = [0x34, 0x12, 0x22, 0x21, 0x6E, 0x34, 0x18, 0x65]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer 3/3: use a packed struct and a raw `uint8_t` pointer to it

Convert a struct to an array in C via a raw pointer without doing any copies of the data, such as into an array via memcpy or via the bitshifting approach. This also has architecture endianness concerns, just like using a union.

The concept is super simple though. Just pack the struct and then look at it as though it was an array of bytes!--like this:

```c
// Use a raw pointer
uint8_t * bytes = (uint8_t*)(&message);
```

It's essentially an explicit, *manual* union, since **you're just looking at the data "through another lens", as I like to call it**, rather than actually copying, manipulating, or changing the data.

Full example:

[struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer.c):

```c
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

typedef struct message_unpacked_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_unpacked_t;

// This MUST be packed to work properly without having padding bytes in the byte array!
typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) message_s
{
    uint16_t time;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint8_t ns;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint8_t ew;
} message_t;


// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("Answer 3/3: use a packed struct and a raw `uint8_t` pointer to it`.\n");

    // demonstrate that packing the struct matters
    printf("sizeof(message_unpacked_t) = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(message_unpacked_t)); // 10 bytes due to padding
    printf("sizeof(message_t) = %zu bytes\n", sizeof(message_t)); // 8 bytes

    message_t message =
    {
        .time = 0x1234,
        .lat = 0x2122,
        .ns = 'n',  // 0x6E
        .lon = 0x1834,
        .ew = 'e', // 0x65
    };

    // Use a raw pointer
    uint8_t * bytes = (uint8_t*)(&message);

    // Print the bytes of `message`
    printf("bytes = [");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(message); i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X", bytes[i]);
        if (i < sizeof(message) - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Build and run command:

```sh
mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -save-temps=obj struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer.c \
-o bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer && bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer
```

Sample output:

> ```
> eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ mkdir -p bin && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -save-temps=obj struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer.c     -o bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer && bin/struct_to_array_via_type_punning_raw_pointer
> Answer 3/3: use a packed struct and a raw `uint8_t` pointer to it`.
> sizeof(message_unpacked_t) = 10 bytes
> sizeof(message_t) = 8 bytes
> bytes = [0x34, 0x12, 0x22, 0x21, 0x6E, 0x34, 0x18, 0x65]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what's already been shared by Gabriel, a lot of stuff in C works as though it's an array from my observations. And I find it helpful to think of stuff in this way.

If you have a function/method that explicitly requires a `uint8_t[8]` type, then this solution would only be a partial solution; but if what you require is ease of data handling and are able to modify your receiving function to use a pointer, then this will be quick and valuable.

To go from a struct type to an array type simply type cast the struct to a `(uint8_t*)`. It's worth noting that doing this produces results that are relative to your system's endianness.

Another interesting thing to note is, at least on my particular Linux environment and also depending on the size of the structure, padding bytes will be appended to your array after conversion. From my experimentation, any structure that produces a fractional logarithm of `size` base 2 contains padding. Where `size` is defined as the total sum of the "`sizeof()`" of each of the particular variables associated with the struct.

The following example quickly shows how to convert structs to arrays and arrays to structs. It also outlines how endianness and `log₂(size)` impacts the resulting array; but not a resulting struct.

```
// main.c - Compilation : gcc main.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sampleStruct{
    uint64_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint8_t c;
}sample_struct_t;

typedef struct sampleStructTwo{
    uint32_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint16_t c;
}sample_struct_ii_t;


int main(void){
    sample_struct_t sample;
    sample.a = 0x8899aabbccddeeff;
    sample.b = 0x44556677;
    sample.c = 0x33;

    uint8_t *sampleArray_ptr;
    sampleArray_ptr = (uint8_t*)&sample;

    printf("\tStruct to pointer array with padding:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(sample_struct_t); i++){
        printf("%x%c", sampleArray_ptr[i], (i == sizeof(sample_struct_t)-1) ? '\n' : ' ');
    }


    sample_struct_ii_t sampleII;
    sampleII.a = 0xaa11aa11;
    sampleII.b = 0xbb22;
    sampleII.c = 0xcc33;
    sampleArray_ptr = (uint8_t *)&sampleII;

    printf("\n\tSecond Struct to pointer array without padding:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(sample_struct_ii_t); i++){
        printf("%x%c", sampleArray_ptr[i], (i == sizeof(sample_struct_ii_t)-1) ? '\n' : ' ');
    }

    uint8_t sampleArray[13] = {
        0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff,
        0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77,
        0x33
    };
    
    sample_struct_t *sample_ptr = (sample_struct_t *)sampleArray;
    
    printf("\n\tArray to pointer struct:\n");
    printf("%lx\n%x\n%x\n", sample_ptr->a, sample_ptr->b, sample_ptr->c);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the result of running the above program on my particular machine.

```
morningstar@madman:: ~/Documents/tests 8=D~ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
...
morningstar@madman:: ~/Documents/tests 8=D~ ./a.out 
    Struct to pointer array with padding:
ff ee dd cc bb aa 99 88 77 66 55 44 33 0 0 0

    Second Struct to pointer array without padding:
11 aa 11 aa 22 bb 33 cc

    Array to pointer struct:
ffeeddccbbaa9988
77665544
33
morningstar@madman:: ~/Documents/tests 8=D~
```

`sample_struct_t` has a size of `uint64_t` + `uint32_t` + `uint8_t` which equals `13`. `log₂(13) = 3.7004` so it has padding bytes, in this instance 3 of them, because it's a *"fractional value"*.

`sample_struct_ii_t` has a size of `uint32_t` + `uint16_t` + `uint16_t` which equals `8`. `log₂(8) = 3` so it has no padding due to the result being a whole number value.