# Use a char[4] or char[8] as a constant int?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have these little functions that takes a small char array and just recasts it as an int or longlong:

```
#define HASH4(x) (*((int*)x))
#define HASH8(x) (*((longlong*)x))

int aValue=HASH4("FOOD");
longlong aBigValue=HASH8("SEXYCOOL");
```

I want to know if there's any way in the C/C++ syntax for me to do this WITHOUT needing the #define?  The reason is, I want to use these in a case structure, like so:

```
switch(something)
{
case HASH4("FOOD"): printf("Food!");break;
case HASH8("SEXYCOOL"): printf("Sexycool!");break;
}
```

...which, it will not let me do.

So is there some way in c syntax to tell it to interpret this four-byte char* as an int?  Or, alternatively, some way to write the define that converts it?

Clarifying: I want to know if there's a way in C/C++ syntax to take the four bytes so that these two statements would be equivalent:

```
int something=Magic("\0\0\0A");
int something=65;

switch(stuff)
{
    case Magic("FOOD"): <-- becomes valid
}
```

...cuz we all know that const char "FOOD" is just four bytes containing 70,79,79,68... is there some way to wrap up a nice MAKEINT(4 bytes) that gets completely handled by the preprocessor or otherwise is indistinguishable from an int or long long?

Comment: Don't use #define for this, look into constexpr functions in C++.  (Macros are kind of a last resource kind of thing). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr. And why are you still using printf (use std::cout with std::format)

Comment: I just want to take the four (or 8) bytes as an int at the compile-time level.  Endian-ness won't matter because it's not being stored-- I'm just trying to get a unique-int that I can use for case structures that can have some readability.  I'm coding in C++.

Comment: Do you look for something like this? `#define HASH4(s) ((((s)[0]*256+(s)[1])*256+(s)[2])*256+(s)[3])` (macros are dangerous, if the argument has side effects, of course ...)

Comment: Hey @chtz  that works! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @KiraHoneybee That wouldn't answer the question. Your question says "any way in the C/C++ syntax for me to do this WITHOUT needing the #define?"

Comment: KiraHoneybee, [I posted @chtz's macro as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714049/4561887). @NicolBolas, I did it without a `#define` too.

Comment: @NicolBolas In the question I had said "alternatively, if there's some way to write a define that converts it."  chtz's trick worked for me, I'm willing to accept his answer.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I'm going to give chtz some time to come back and answer it if he wants to.  If he doesn't in a day I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Re: `"FOOD"` is four bytes containing ..." -- no, it's **five** chars; there's a terminating nul character. And we don't **know** the values. We might assume that the character encoding is ASCII, which it almost always is these days.

Comment: Let's not split hairs-- I just want to quickly and easily hash a 4 (or 8) char* character string into an int, the trailing zero doesn't matter for my purposes, which is only to have human readable superfast values that I can branch on.

Comment: @chtz, great job on that. Note that for little-endian systems, including x86-64, you need to reverse the order of the hash, and do this instead: `#define HASH4(s) ((((s)[3]*256+(s)[2])*256+(s)[1])*256+(s)[0])`. See full example runs and conversions from string to an unsigned int and back again [in my full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714049/4561887).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: [@chtz's hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75713727/use-a-char4-or-char8-as-a-constant-int/75714049#comment133567054_75713727) totally works. It tricks the compiler into not realizing it's building an int from a char array.

### Solution 1/4: use a macro to hack together a `uint32_t` by manually calculating it from 4 bytes

Update 2: consider endianness. x86-64 systems are little-endian. I originally mistakenly used the big-endian hash:

```cpp
// For big-endian byte ordering
uint32_t num = ((chars[0]*256 + chars[1])*256 + chars[2])*256 + chars[3];

// Update 2: reverse the order for correct endianness:
// For little-endian byte ordering
uint32_t num = ((chars[3]*256 + chars[2])*256 + chars[1])*256 + chars[0];
```

**test.cpp:**

```cpp
///usr/bin/env ccache g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu++17 "$0" -o /tmp/a && /tmp/a "$@"; exit
// For the line just above, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491834/4561887

#include <iostream>

#define HASH4(s) ((((s)[0]*256+(s)[1])*256+(s)[2])*256+(s)[3])

void check_int(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case HASH4("FOOD"):
        printf("FOOD\n");
        break;
    case HASH4("TREE"):
        printf("TREE\n");
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    int something = HASH4("FOOD");
    printf("something = %i\n", something); // something = 1179602756
    check_int(something);

    something = 1179602756;
    check_int(something);


    // ----------------------------
    // withOUT using a #define now
    // ----------------------------

    something = ((('F'*256+'O')*256+'O')*256+'D');

    switch(something)
    {
        case ((('F'*256+'O')*256+'O')*256+'D'):
            printf("FOOD\n");
            break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Run cmd:

```bash
chmod +x test.cpp   # make executable
./test.cpp          # run it
```

Output:

```
Test
something = 1179602756
FOOD
FOOD
FOOD
```

With*out* using a `#define`: this works fine because `((('F'*256+'O')*256+'O')*256+'D')` is a constant expression!--it is totally calculated into a constant value at compile-time.

### Solution 2/4 (better): use a constant expression function hack instead of the macro hack above

[@Pepijn Kramer is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75713876/4561887) that `constexpr` functions can be used to replace macros which just do pre-compile-time calculations. In other words, `constexpr` functions can replace *some* macros. `constexpr` functions may be preferred because they have type safety and checking and avoid the double-evaluation problem that macros have when you pass an expression or assignment into them.

`constexpr` functions will evaluate into `constexpr` results *during compile-time* if able, and as regular results *during runtime* otherwise. So, they are like a mix of the functionality of *some* macros + regular functions.

Here's one solution, passing a `std::array` of 4 chars into a `constexpr` function:

```cpp
///usr/bin/env ccache g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu++17 "$0" -o /tmp/a && /tmp/a "$@"; exit
// For the line just above, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491834/4561887

#include <array>
#include <iostream>

constexpr uint32_t hash4chars(const std::array<char, 4>& chars)
{
    // For big-endian byte ordering
    // uint32_t num = ((chars[0]*256 + chars[1])*256 + chars[2])*256 + chars[3];

    // Update: reverse the order for correct endianness:
    // For little-endian byte ordering
    uint32_t num = ((chars[3]*256 + chars[2])*256 + chars[1])*256 + chars[0];
    return num;
}

void check_int(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case hash4chars({'F', 'O', 'O', 'D'}):
        printf("FOOD\n");
        break;
    case hash4chars({'T', 'R', 'E', 'E'}):
        printf("TREE\n");
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    uint32_t num = hash4chars({'F', 'O', 'O', 'D'});
    printf("num = %u\n", num);
    check_int(num);

    // convert the num back to a char array to check that it was converted
    // correctly
    const char* str = (const char*)(&num);
    printf("%c%c%c%c\n", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Run and output, showing that the 4 bytes in `FOOD` turn into the `uint32_t` number of `1146048326`, and that number turns back into the 4 chars `FOOD` on my x86-64 Linux system (which is little endian):

```bash
$ ./test.cpp 
Test
num = 1146048326
FOOD
FOOD
```

### Solution 3/4: (best so far) `constexpr` function hack using a `std::string_view` as input, instead of the `std::array` just above

Even better still, use a `std::string_view` as the input parameter so you can still pass in raw C-string to it. Here is a full example:

```cpp
///usr/bin/env ccache g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu++17 "$0" -o /tmp/a && /tmp/a "$@"; exit
// For the line just above, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491834/4561887

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

constexpr uint32_t hash4chars(const std::string_view& sv)
{
    // Error checking: ensure all inputs have only 4 chars.
    // Note: as really crude error checking, we'll just return the sentinel
    // value of `UINT32_MAX` if this error occurs. Better techniques exist
    if (sv.size() != 4)
    {
        printf("Error: the string view should be 4 chars long!\n");
        return UINT32_MAX;
    }

    // static_assert(sv.size() == 4); // doesn't work

    // For big-endian byte ordering
    // uint32_t num = ((sv[0]*256 + sv[1])*256 + sv[2])*256 + sv[3];

    // Update: reverse the order for correct endianness:
    // For little-endian byte ordering
    uint32_t num = ((sv[3]*256 + sv[2])*256 + sv[1])*256 + sv[0];
    return num;
}

void check_int(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case hash4chars("FOOD"):
        printf("FOOD\n");
        break;
    case hash4chars("TREE"):
        printf("TREE\n");
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    uint32_t num = hash4chars("FOOD");
    printf("num = %u\n", num);
    check_int(num);

    // convert the num back to a char array to check that it was converted
    // correctly
    const char* str = (const char*)(&num);
    printf("%c%c%c%c\n", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Run and output (exact same as previously):

```bash
$ ./test.cpp 
Test
num = 1146048326
FOOD
FOOD
```

### Solution 4/4: don't convert 4 bytes to integers; just hash the string directly, as a string view, using built-in C++ hash functions

Based on the fact you are calling your macro `HASH4()` and `HASH8()` in the question, it seems you really just want a unique or near-unique hash of the input string? ie: you don't actually need to convert its equivalent-space integer representation; rather, you just need a hash of it.

In that case, you can also just use C++'s built-in `std::hash<>{}()` functor. See here:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash - general documentation

   1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/hash - documentation on the `std::string_view` specialization of it

      1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv - meaning of `operator""sv()` function, used as `"my_string"sv` to produce a `std::string_view` from C-string `"my_string"` in the examples just above

*But*, `std::hash<>{}()` is not a `constexpr` function, so you can *not* use it in switch cases either! Rather, you must use the `if` `else` style of checking.

How to read `std::hash<>{}()`:

1. `std` is the namespace
2. `<>` specifies the template type
3. `{}` constructs a default object of this class type
4. `()` calls the `operator()` (parenthesis function-like [or "functor"] operator; see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash/operator()) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356993/4561887)) on this object, which in this case is the function to perform the hash on the parameters inside those parenthesis.

Note: the following code works great, and may be the most beloved by many C++ people, but I find it pretty complicated and perhaps too "C++"-y. Your call. It also isn't a `constexpr` expression. I'm happy I have finally reached the point after 3 years of daily C++ usage that I can even read and write this myself, however, and having access to a quick hash of C-strings (interpreted as `std::string_view`s) is in fact nice to have as part of the C++ language.

```cpp
///usr/bin/env ccache g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu++17 "$0" -o /tmp/a && /tmp/a "$@"; exit
// For the line just above, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491834/4561887

#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

void check_hash(std::size_t hash)
{
    if (hash == std::hash<std::string_view>{}(std::string_view{"FOOD", 4}))
    {
        printf("FOOD\n");
    }
    else if (hash == std::hash<std::string_view>{}(std::string_view{"TREE", 4}))
    {
        printf("TREE\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    std::size_t num
        = std::hash<std::string_view>{}(std::string_view{"FOOD", 4});
    printf("num = %lu\n", num);
    check_hash(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Run and output:

```bash
$ ./test.cpp 
Test
num = 16736621008042147638
FOOD
```

That `std::hash` functor is pretty ugly, so you if you like, you can beautify it a bit by wrapping it with a macro:

```cpp
#define HASH(string, num_chars) \
    std::hash<std::string_view>{}(std::string_view{(string), (num_chars)})
```

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

#define HASH(string, num_chars) \
    std::hash<std::string_view>{}(std::string_view{(string), (num_chars)})

void check_hash(std::size_t hash)
{
    if (hash == HASH("FOOD", 4))
    {
        printf("FOOD\n");
    }
    else if (hash == HASH("TREE", 4))
    {
        printf("TREE\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    std::size_t num = HASH("FOOD", 4);
    printf("num = %lu\n", num);
    check_hash(num);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same as just above.

### Going further

If you want to look more into conversions of memory blobs to and from byte arrays, see also my other answers here:

1. How to convert a `struct` variable to `uint8_t` array in C:

   1. [Answer 1/3: use a union and a packed struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984037/4561887)
   2. [Answer 2/3: convert a struct to an array of bytes via manual bit-shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984464/4561887)
   3. [Answer 3/3: use a packed struct and a raw uint8_t pointer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984614/4561887)

### Other info to consider and understand

To make 4 bytes get interpreted as a constant 4-byte int (`const int32_t`), simply use

```cpp
// this
#define CONST_INT32(bytes) (*((const int32_t*)(bytes)))

// instead of this
#define CONST_INT32(bytes) (*((int32_t*)(bytes)))
```

ie: add `const` before your pointer cast.

But, that gets you a `const int32_t`, which is *not* the same as a `constexpr int32_t` constant expression int32_t. A *constant expression* tells the compiler that this piece of memory won't be trifled with, edited, or reinterpret-casted as another type. The fact that you are reinterpret-casting 4 bytes into an int via a macro already violates this.

So, no, in C++ there is no preprocessor macro way I am aware of to forcefully interpret 4 bytes as a `constexpr int`.

You can reinterpret 4 bytes as a `const int` instead, but that's not the same thing. Only `constexpr` types can be used as cases in a switch statement, so [@dbush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75713763/4561887) is right. Use an `if` `else` to check the `const int` values instead.

Note: if you declare a `const int`, the compiler may see it could also be a `constexpr int` and make that decision for you. So, this runs:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    const int CASE1 = 7; // compiler sees these could also be constexpr
    const int CASE2 = 8; // compiler sees these could also be constexpr

    int something = CASE1;

    switch(something)
    {
    case CASE1:
        printf("CASE1\n");
        break;
    case CASE2:
        printf("CASE2\n");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

...as well as this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";

    constexpr int CASE1 = 7; // you are explicitly making these constexpr
    constexpr int CASE2 = 8; // you are explicitly making these constexpr

    int something = CASE1;

    switch(something)
    {
    case CASE1:
        printf("CASE1\n");
        break;
    case CASE2:
        printf("CASE2\n");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use constexpr functions instead of macros. e.g.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// create a constexpr hash function which may
// be used both at compile and at runtime.
// I used std::string_view since I am used to that.
// but you can also use a char* and use strlen

static constexpr auto hash(const std::string_view& str)
{
    std::array<std::size_t, 4> primes{ 1,3,5,7 };
    std::size_t count = std::min(primes.size(), str.size());

    std::size_t hash{ 0ul };
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < count; n++)
    {
        hash += (primes[n] * static_cast<std::size_t>(str[n]));
    }

    return hash;
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t something = hash("FOOD");

    switch (something)
    {
        case hash("FOOD"): std::cout << "Food!"; break;
        case hash("SEXYCOOL"): std::cout << "Sexycool!"; break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you (essentially) only want to accept string literals, you could use `char const str[n]` with a template parameter `int n`.

Comment: This looks promising!  But I am limited to C++11... I changed it to char const str[4] as suggested, but my switch structure still tells me "case expression not constant".  Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider switching to C++20. There's a lot you can do without macros and explicit type punning.

Answer (score 1):

The values for a `case` label are required to be constant expressions, and expressions such as `(*((int*)x))` don't qualify.  The fact that you're using a `#define` doesn't matter.

You'll need to use a `if`...`else` chain for this.

```
if (something == HASH4("FOOD")) {
    printf("Food!");
} else if (something == HASH8("SEXYCOOL")) {
    printf("Sexycool!");
}
```

Comment: I get that.  The question is whether there is some way, in C++ syntax (or with a clever #define) to have it interpret the four bytes in a const char* as a const integer instead of a string.