# Bug when converting a byte array to a uint64

Tags: c, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to figure out a bug when converting a byte array to a `uint64_t` (`unsigned long long`).

I know you can do that with shifts, but that's not my question. I want to do this with multiplications. I would like to know why the multiplications do not go as planned in some cases.

The result of this code is correct:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char byte[8];
    unsigned long long x;

    byte[0] = 0x15;
    byte[1] = 0x15; 
    byte[2] = 0x17;
    byte[3] = 0x18; 
    byte[4] = 0x19;
    byte[5] = 0x20;
    byte[6] = 0x21;
    byte[7] = 0x12;
            
    x = (byte[0] * 0x100000000000000) +
        (byte[1] * 0x1000000000000) + 
        (byte[2] * 0x10000000000) + 
        (byte[3] * 0x100000000);

    x = x +
        (byte[4] << 24) + 
        (byte[5] << 16) + 
        (byte[6] << 8) + 
        byte[7];

    printf("%llx\n", x);
}
```

The result is `1515171819202112`, which is correct.

But with this case, where I use these bytes instead:

```c
    byte[0] = 0x15;
    byte[1] = 0x92;  // changed 
    byte[2] = 0x53;  // changed
    byte[3] = 0x22;  // changed
    byte[4] = 0xec;  // changed
    byte[5] = 0x33;  // changed
    byte[6] = 0x99;  // changed
    byte[7] = 0x12;
```

...the result is wrong.

I get:
159253**21**ec339912.

But, it should be:
159253**22**ec339912.

**Why? What is the bug?**

Comment: Compiler warnings will help debug this. `warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long long' [-Wsign-conversion]`

Comment: @Schwern, I just ran this code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu17 main.c` and got no warnings nor errors whatsoever. I tested both cases in the question.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Add `-Wconversion` which implies `-Wsign-conversion`. I also recommend `-pedantic` (which reveals the main signature is wrong) and sticking to official C dialects while learning.

Answer (score 7):

In this subexpression:

```
byte[4]<<24
```

You start with an `unsigned char` value.  This value first gets *promoted* to type `int`.  This behavior is detailed in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding arithmetic conversions:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>   the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as
> restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to
> an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are
> called the *integer promotions*. All other types are unchanged by the
> integer promotions.

So the promoted value of `byte[4]` has type `int` which is signed and (most likely) 32 bit.  You then shift this `int` value left by 24.  Given that the original value was `0xec`, this results in a value of 1 being shifted into the sign bit of the resulting `int` value.

Shifting a 1 into the sign bit results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This is spelled out in section 6.5.7p4 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding bitwise shift operators:

> The result of `E1 << E2` is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
> bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
> the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and
> nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type,
> then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.**

You can correct this by first casting the value to `unsigned long long` so that the shift is valid.

```
x=x+((unsigned long long)byte[4]<<24)+(byte[5]<<16)+(byte[6]<<8)+byte[7];
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @dbush, `byte[4] << 24` has undefined behavior when `byte[4]` has a value greater than `127`.

On your architecture the most likely effect of shifting a `1` bit into the sign bit of type `int` is to create a negative value: `0xec << 24` evaluates to `-335544320`. In the expression `x + (byte[4] << 24) + (byte[5] << 16) + (byte[6] << 8) + byte[7]`, adding `(byte[4] << 24)` causes the `int` value to be converted to `unsigned long long` as `0xffffffec000000` which effectively subtracts `0x100000000` from the high 32 bits. This explains the observed behavior.

This is non intuitive but not related to the `<<` shift operator. The same problem would occur with this code:

```
    x = (byte[0] * 0x100000000000000) +
        (byte[1] * 0x1000000000000) + 
        (byte[2] * 0x10000000000) + 
        (byte[3] * 0x100000000) +
        (byte[4] * 0x1000000) +
        (byte[5] * 0x10000) +
        (byte[6] * 0x100) +
        (byte[7] * 0x1);
```

As a matter of fact, there are 2 instances of potential undefined behavior in the above expression: `byte[0] * 0x100000000000000` and `byte[4] * 0x1000000` because of signed arithmetic overflow.

You can use multiplications to achieve your conversion by forcing `unsigned long long` arithmetics as an alternative to shifts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long read64_mul(const unsigned char *byte) {
    return byte[0] * 0x100000000000000ULL +
           byte[1] * 0x1000000000000ULL + 
           byte[2] * 0x10000000000ULL + 
           byte[3] * 0x100000000ULL +
           byte[4] * 0x1000000ULL +
           byte[5] * 0x10000ULL +
           byte[6] * 0x100ULL +
           byte[7] * 0x1ULL;
}

unsigned long long read64_shift(const unsigned char *byte) {
    return ((unsigned long long)byte[0] << 56) |
           ((unsigned long long)byte[1] << 48) |
           ((unsigned long long)byte[2] << 40) |
           ((unsigned long long)byte[3] << 32) |
           ((unsigned long long)byte[4] << 24) |
           ((unsigned long long)byte[5] << 16) |
           ((unsigned long long)byte[6] << 8) |
           ((unsigned long long)byte[7] << 0);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char byte[8] = {
        0x15, 0x92, 0x53, 0x22, 0xec, 0x33, 0x99, 0x12
    };
            
    unsigned long long x1 = read64_mul(byte);
    unsigned long long x2 = read64_shift(byte);

    printf("%llx\n%llx\n", x1, x2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
15925322ec339912
15925322ec339912
```

Yet this does not seem to be a good idea: as can be verified on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dvd95qf8W), both **gcc** and **clang** recognise the expression and generate optimal code for the shift version but they do not recognise the multiplication approach and generate naive code even at `-O3`, although **clang** efficiently inlines both calls for the known array contents.

Answer (score 0):

##### Reinterpret cast: looking at an array of bytes "through the lens of" a `uint64_t` type

In addition to [the answer that directly answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77284467/4561887), I'd like to point out that you can simply reinterpret-cast an array of bytes into a `uint64_t` type as well, like this:

```c
uint64_t *val = (uint64_t*)byte;
```

However, you've written your conversion code to interpret the bytes as [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) ("big beginnian" as I like to call it: most-significant byte first--at the lowest address in memory), and I know that I'm on a little-endian x86-64 Linux Ubuntu machine, so I must swap the bytes from big-endian to little-endian before I can interpret them in order for me to get the same results as you:

```c
swap_bytes_in_array(byte, sizeof(byte));

uint64_t *val = (uint64_t*)byte;
```

Here's the full code:

**[byte_array_reinterpret_cast_to_uint64_t.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/byte_array_reinterpret_cast_to_uint64_t.c)** from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```c
///usr/bin/env ccache gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu17 "$0" -o /tmp/a -lm && /tmp/a "$@"; exit
// For the line just above, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491834/4561887

#include <inttypes.h> // for `PRIu64`, etc.
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

// From my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64056527/4561887
/// \brief          Swap all the bytes in an array to convert from little-endian
///                 byte order to big-endian byte order, or vice versa.
/// \note           Works for arrays of any size. Swaps the bytes **in place**
///                 in the array.
/// \param[in,out]  byte_array  The array in which to swap the bytes in-place.
/// \param[in]      len         The length (in bytes) of the array.
/// \return         None
void swap_bytes_in_array(uint8_t *byte_array, size_t len)
{
    size_t i_left = 0;         // index for left side of the array
    size_t i_right = len - 1;  // index for right side of the array
    while (i_left < i_right)
    {
        // swap left and right bytes
        uint8_t left_copy = byte_array[i_left];
        byte_array[i_left] = byte_array[i_right];
        byte_array[i_right] = left_copy;
        i_left++;
        i_right--;
    }
}

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    uint8_t byte[8];

    // assume the bytes are stored in big-endian order, for instance

    // // Test 1
    // byte[0] = 0x15;
    // byte[1] = 0x15;
    // byte[2] = 0x17;
    // byte[3] = 0x18;
    // byte[4] = 0x19;
    // byte[5] = 0x20;
    // byte[6] = 0x21;
    // byte[7] = 0x12;

    // Test 2
    byte[0] = 0x15;
    byte[1] = 0x92;  // changed
    byte[2] = 0x53;  // changed
    byte[3] = 0x22;  // changed
    byte[4] = 0xec;  // changed
    byte[5] = 0x33;  // changed
    byte[6] = 0x99;  // changed
    byte[7] = 0x12;

    // swap the bytes around to little-endian order
    swap_bytes_in_array(byte, sizeof(byte));

    // Now reinterpret-cast the bytes as a uint64_t; ie: look at the bytes
    // through the lens of a uint64_t, as I like to call it.
    uint64_t *val = (uint64_t*)byte;

    // Print the uint64_t value
    printf("val (as uint64_t) = %" PRIu64 "\n", *val);        // as an unsigned integer
    printf("val (in hex)      = 0x%08" PRIX64 "\n\n", *val);  // in hex

    // now change the bytes in the array
    *val = 12345;

    // print the uint64_t value again
    printf("val (as uint64_t) = %" PRIu64 "\n", *val);        // as an unsigned integer
    printf("val (in hex)      = 0x%08" PRIX64 "\n\n", *val);  // in hex

    // and print out the bytes:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(byte); i++)
    {
        printf("byte[%zu] = 0x%02X\n", i, byte[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Run and output on my little-endian x86-64 Linux Ubuntu machine. Notice that I get `0x15925322EC339912`, like you expect:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ c/byte_array_reinterpret_cast_to_uint64_t.c
val (as uint64_t) = 1554396230853040402
val (in hex)      = 0x15925322EC339912

val (as uint64_t) = 12345
val (in hex)      = 0x00003039

byte[0] = 0x39
byte[1] = 0x30
byte[2] = 0x00
byte[3] = 0x00
byte[4] = 0x00
byte[5] = 0x00
byte[6] = 0x00
byte[7] = 0x00
```

### References

1. My `swap_bytes_in_array()` function: [How to swap the bytes in *any* basic data type or array of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64056527/4561887)

### See also

1. My answer: [Portability of using union for conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67206563/4561887)
2. My 3 answers to [How to convert a struct variable to uint8_t array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69983795/4561887):

   1. [Answer 1/3: use a union and a packed struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984037/4561887).
   2. [Answer 2/3: convert a struct to an array of bytes via manual bit-shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984464/4561887).
   3. [Answer 3/3: use a packed struct and a raw uint8_t pointer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984614/4561887).
3. [endianness_get.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/endianness_get.c) - my code to programmatically determine if you're on a big-endian or little-endian machine.