# Adding int type to uint64_t c++

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding conversion of integers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int N,R,W,H,D;
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    uint64_t sum_2 = 0;
    cin >> W >> H >> D;
    sum += static_cast<uint64_t>(W) * H * D * 100;
    sum_2 += W * H * D * 100;
    
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << sum_2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I thought, that `sum` should be equal to `sum_2`, because `uint64_t` type is bigger than `int` type and during arithmetic operations compiler chooses bigger type(which is uint64_t). So by my understanding, `sum_2` must have `uint64_t` type. But it has int type.

Can you explain my why sum_2 was converted to `int`? Why didn't it stay `uint64_t`?

Comment: The `W * H * D * 100` part is perform with `int` types because all the types in that sequence are `int` - only the assignment converts the result of this calculation into an `uint64_t`

Comment: `sum_2` **does** have `uint64_t` type.  But for the reason UnholySheep gave, you only fed `int` values into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Undefined behavior signed*-integer overflow/underflow, and *well-defined behavior unsigned*-integer overflow/underflow, in C and C++

If I enter `200`, `300`, and `358` for `W`, `H`, and `D`, I get the following output, which makes perfect sense for my gcc compiler on a 64-bit Linux machine:

```
2148000000
18446744071562584320
```

Why does this make perfect sense?

Well, the default type is `int`, which is `int32_t` for the gcc compiler on a 64-bit Linux machine, and its max value is 2^32/2-1 = 2147483647, and its min value is -2147483648. The line `sum_2 += W * H * D * 100;` does *`int`* arithmetic since that's the type of each variable there, `100` included, and no explicit cast is used. So, after doing `int` arithmetic, it then implicitly casts the `int` result into a `uint64_t` as it stores the result into the `uint64_t sum_2` variable. The `int` arithmetic on the right-hand side prior to that point, however, results in `2148000000`, which has ***undefined behavior* signed integer overflow** over the top of the max `int` value and back down to the min `int` value and up again.

Even though according to the C and C++ standards, *signed integer* overflow or underflow is **undefined behavior**, in the `gcc` compiler, I know that signed integer overflow happens to roll over to negative values if it is not optimized out. This, by default, is still "undefined behavior", and a bug, however, and must *not* be relied upon by default. See notes below for details and information on how to make this well-defined behavior via a gcc extension. Anyway, 2148000000 - 2147483647 = 516353 up-counts, the first of which causes roll-over. The first count up rolls over to the min `int32_t` value of -2147483648, and the next (516353 - 1 = 516352) counts go up to -2147483648 + 516352 = -2146967296. So, the result of `W * H * D * 100` for the inputs above is now `-2146967296`, based on **undefined behavior**. Next, that value is implicitly cast from an `int` (`int32_t` in this case) to a `uint64_t` in order to store it from an `int` (`int32_t` in this case) into the `uint64_t sum_2` variable, resulting in *well-defined behavior unsigned integer underflow*. You start with -2146967296. The first down-count underflows down to `uint64_t` max, which is 2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615. Now subtract the remaining 2146967296 - 1 = 2146967295 counts from that and you get 18446744073709551615 - 2146967295 = `18446744071562584320`, just as shown above!

Voila! With a little compiler and hardware architecture understanding, and some expected but undefined behavior, the result is perfectly explainable and makes sense!

To easily see the negative value, add this to your code:

```cpp
int sum_3 = W*H*D*100;
cout << sum_3 << endl;  // output: -2146967296
```

### Notes

1. Never intentionally leave undefined behavior in your code. That is known as a *bug*. You do *not* have to write ISO C++, however! If you can find compiler documentation indicating a certain behavior is well-defined, that's ok, so long as you know you are writing in the g++ language and not the C++ language, and don't expect your code to work the same across compilers. Here is an example where I do that: [Using Unions for "type punning" is fine in C, and fine in gcc's C++ as well (**as a gcc [g++] extension)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67206563/4561887). I'm generally okay with relying on compiler extensions like this. Just be aware of what you're doing is all.
2. @user17732522 makes a great point [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199782/adding-int-type-to-uint64-t-c/73200042#comment129279776_73200042):

   > *"in the gcc compiler, I know that signed integer overflow happens to roll over to negative values."*: That is not correct by-default. By-default GCC assumes that signed overflow does not happen and applies optimizations based on that. There is the `-fwrapv` and/or `-fno-strict-overflow` flag to enforce wrapping behavior. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options.

   Take a look at that link above (or even better, this one, to always point to the latest gcc documentation instead of the documentation for just one version: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options). Even though signed-integer overflow and underflow is *undefined behavior* (a bug!) according to the C and C++ standards, gcc allows, by extension, to make it *well-defined behavior* (*not* a bug!) so long as you use the proper gcc build flags. Using `-fwrapv` makes signed-integer overflow/underflow well-defined behavior as a gcc extension. Additionally, `-fwrapv-pointer` allows pointers to safely overflow and underflow when used in pointer arithmetic, and `-fno-strict-overflow` applies both `-fwrapv` and `-fwrapv-pointer`. The relevant documentation is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options (emphasis added):

   > These machine-independent options control the interface conventions used in code generation.
   >
   > Most of them have both positive and negative forms; the negative form of `-ffoo` is `-fno-foo`.
   >
   > ...
   >
   > - **`-fwrapv`**
   >   This option instructs the compiler to assume that signed arithmetic overflow of addition, subtraction and multiplication wraps around using twos-complement representation. This flag enables some optimizations and disables others. The options `-ftrapv` and `-fwrapv` override each other, so using `-ftrapv -fwrapv` on the command-line results in `-fwrapv` being effective. Note that only active options override, so using `-ftrapv -fwrapv -fno-wrapv` on the command-line results in `-ftrapv` being effective.
   > - **`-fwrapv-pointer`**
   >   This option instructs the compiler to assume that pointer arithmetic overflow on addition and subtraction wraps around using twos-complement representation. This flag disables some optimizations which assume pointer overflow is invalid.
   > - **`-fstrict-overflow`**
   >   This option implies `-fno-wrapv -fno-wrapv-pointer` and **when negated [as `-fno-strict-overflow`] implies `-fwrapv -fwrapv-pointer`**.

   So, relying on signed-integer overflow or underflow withOUT using the proper gcc extension flags above is **undefined behavior**, and therefore a bug, and can *not* be safely relied upon! It may be optimized out by the compiler and not work reliably as intended without the gcc extension flags above.

### My test code

Here is my total code I used for some quick checks to write this answer. I ran it with the gcc/g++ compiler on a 64-bit Linux machine. I did *not* use the `-fwrapv` or `-fno-strict-overflow` flags, so all signed integer overflow or underflow demonstrated below is *undefined behavior*, a bug, and cannot be relied upon safely without those gcc extension flags. The fact that it works is circumstantial, as the compiler could, by default, choose to optimize out the overflows in unexpected ways.

If you run this on an 8-bit microcontroller such as an Arduino Uno, you'd get different results since an `int` is a 2-byte `int16_t` by default, instead! But, now that you understand the principles, you could figure out the expected result. (Also, I think 64-bit values don't exist on that architecture, so they become 32-bit values).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int N,R,W,H,D;
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    uint64_t sum_2 = 0;
    // cin >> W >> H >> D;
    W = 200;
    H = 300;
    D = 358;
    sum += static_cast<uint64_t>(W) * H * D * 100;
    sum_2 += W * H * D * 100;
    
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << sum_2 << endl;
    
    int sum_3 = W*H*D*100;
    cout << sum_3 << endl;
    
    sum_2 = -1; // underflow to uint64_t max
    cout << sum_2 << endl;
    
    sum_2 = 18446744073709551615ULL - 2146967295;
    cout << sum_2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

### See also

1. Here's a newer answer I recently gave on this topic: [In C , why does this `main` function with an incrementing integer never crash from overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77226496/4561887)

Comment: "_in the gcc compiler, I know that signed integer overflow happens to roll over to negative values._": That is not correct by-default. By-default GCC assumes that signed overflow does not happen and applies optimizations based on that. There is the `-fwrapv` and/or `-fno-strict-overflow` flag to enforce wrapping behavior. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options.

Comment: @user17732522, thank you for that information! I've substantially updated my answer to incorporate it. I have never used the gcc flags to make signed-integer overflow and underflow well-defined behavior before.

Answer (score 4):

Just a short version of [@Gabriel Staples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73200042/2410359) good answer.

> "and during arithmetic operations compiler chooses bigger type(which is uint64_t)"

There is no `uin64_t` in `W * H * D * 100`, just four `int`.  *After* this multiplication, the `int` product (which overflowed and is UB) is assigned to an `uint64_t`.

Instead, use `100LLU * W * H * D` to perform a wider *unsigned* multiplication.