# In C , why does this `main` function with an incrementing integer never crash from overflow?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller

In C, the most basic `main` function for embedded system like an stm32 is:

```c
int main(void) {
    int i = 0;

    while(1) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

But, since `i` is an integer, won't it overflow and, therefore, create problem at some point?

Also, is it safe to use the same tactic (using `while(1) i++`) to loop around while waiting for a specific interrupt?

Edit : thanks for all the answer. My bad for not knowing that overflow handler were so much different from C and C++. Now I know !

Comment: There are two undefined behaviors in two lines.

Comment: It will overflow, immediately triggering Undefined Behavior since it is a signed integer type.  And that is not "safe to use".

Comment: Please read [this progress guarantee reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Progress_guarantee). A truly infinite loop isn't strictly allowed by C++.

Comment: In C++, an `int` doesn't "overflow" *per se*, it more of an **undefined behavior** kind of thing (which probably overflows, but also might do something else... like crash).  In contrast, `unsigned int` has well behaved wraparound behavior on overflow.

Comment: And please note that while there are constructs and other similarities between C and C++, they are two ***very*** different languages. Their respective specifications could contain minute differences in wording, making things like this very different. Please avoid tagging both languages. Please see [the C++ tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) (for example) and read about using the C and C++ tags together.

Comment: @Eljay: If you are going to make pedantic points about terminology, then check them first. You have it reversed from the C and C++ standards. C++ 2020 draft n4849 6.8.1 says, in a note, “Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow. Overflow for signed arithmetic yields undefined behavior (7.1).” As used by the standards, signed integer arithmetic overflows, because a specified result (such as the sum for an addition) cannot be represented in the result type, and unsigned arithmetic never overflows, because operations are specified to wrap, so the specified result is always representable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that's very interesting wording. I've never thought of it that way, but that makes total sense. In that case we are all (almost all) using the word "overflow" incorrectly--technically, pedantically, language-lawyerly.

Comment: C and C++ are very different here. You need to make a more focused question about one single programming language at a time. Also this has nothing to do with embedded systems since `int main (void)` isn't used.

Comment: Signed integer overflow is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and so is an infinite loop without side effects, so your program is simply broken and the compiler is under no obligation to generate anything in particular. It probably just optimizes the entire loop away.

Comment: @EricPostpischil • I appreciate the correction & clarification, thank you!

Comment: In the question you indicate this is a basic `main` function for STM32. Can you post a link to an example where you see this? I don't recall seeing STM32 examples incrementing signed integers and allowing roll-over/overflow like this.

Comment: @Lundin, what do you mean that "`int main(void)` isn't used?" If you define `int main(void)`, it runs automatically and is therefore used.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Embedded (_freestanding_) systems use an implementation-defined form of `main`, since returning `int` is senseless. In C that usually means `void main (void)`. In C++ I suppose you curse at the PC programmers who wrote the standard, then find a way to name it `void not_main_I_promise (void)`.

Comment: @Lundin, I see what you mean. I'm pretty sure I've seen both `void main(void)` and `int main(void)` in microcontrollers, with both being equal. In my answer I point to Arduino using `int main(void)`. Embedded frequently has to have minor deviations and extensions beyond the standard to support these and other nuances outside the norm.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Those who designed the Arduino tool chain generally didn't have much of a clue about anything. But it is actually C++ in that case, and the C++ standard is a bit dysfunctional there. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518

Comment: @GabrielStaples I use atollic which is a eclipse based IDE to program an STM32 for a class at university and when you create a new embedded project, the main file/function contains that infinite loop. Also, fun fact, the function is define with the type int, but there is no return whatsoever in the main because you're not supposed to reached the end of the main function... but it's still odd.

Comment: B1ackAnge1, you are correct. I was going to install [Atollic TrueSTUDIO](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/truestudio.html) to check, but instead found this YouTube video showing the `main` function just as you said [here at this time](https://youtu.be/Qlue89q-rWU?t=1354) and [here for the rest of `main`](https://youtu.be/Qlue89q-rWU?t=1359). That's pretty silly. They should not use signed integers like that.

Comment: Regarding having no return in `main`, I believe that is allowed as a compiler extension in C, and perhaps as part of the standard in C++. The assumption is `return 0;` if not explicitly said. I can remove `return 0;` from any regular C or C++ program on a PC and it builds and runs just fine with gcc.

Comment: Also, you really should be using STM32CubeIDE in your class instead. Atollic TrueSTUDIO is dead and no longer maintained as of 2017. See here: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/truestudio.html: "Updates to Atollic TrueSTUDIO are discontinued since 2017". ST has done a tremendous effort to make STM32CubeIDE fully cross-compatible with all major OSs, and it's a great tool.

Comment: @Lundin, I can see [from your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/4561887) that C in a freestanding environment (ex: on an mcu) allows "any form or name of main", but C++ requires the `int` return type. I see no problem with this. It makes no difference anyway. Just don't get to the end of `main()` on an mcu.

Comment: @Lundin, as for "Those who designed the Arduino tool chain generally didn't have much of a clue about anything", I have to disagree not just strongly, but incredibly strongly with this. I've read a ton of the Arduino source code & am overall extremely impressed with its design, features, and usability. They could even be used as a base model of how to properly blend C & C++ on an mcu. Also, their usability: toolchain, ease-of-compiling, preconfigured serial IO & `print` over serial is one of the top and most influential innovations in my lifetime, creating millions of new embedded developers.

Comment: I myself owe my existence as an embedded software developer, electrical engineer, and software engineer in general, to Arduino. And, in using STM32 and other systems professionally, I have far more gripes with the quality of these more mainstream "professional" toolchains, libraries, software, support code, and example code, than I have with the quality of Arduino. Just look at Atollic TrueSTUDIO's example in the question above, for instance.

Comment: `My bad for not knowing that overflow handler were so much different from C and C++.` They're not different.

Comment: @GabrielStaples "I see no problem with this. It makes no difference anyway" Since main() is treated much like every other function, then when the CRT calls main, having a return value means that the CRT must stack useless stuff according to the calling convention. So it does make a difference: you waste x number of bytes on the stack which can never be used or recovered.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Not going to detail this into some pro/con against Arduino, but just to briefly scrape the top of the bad practice iceberg, some of the major problems are: preaching the use completely outdated electronics, encouraging particularly horrible design calls such as using C++ or floating point on a 8 bit MCU, teaching very bad design patterns such as busy-wait and polling a free running timer, encouraging heap allocation. Etc etc. Which can be summarized as: not having a clue about pretty much everything embedded.

Comment: @GabrielStaples As for ST's various tool chains and libraries being unfriendly and unsuitable for most purposes, I completely agree. I have used STM32 occasionally but never with ST tools and libs. And I have a very strong aversion against Eclipse in any form or shape.

Comment: Regarding my comment "C and C++ are very different here", I was mainly referring to the way C++ (and non-conforming clang in C mode) destroys your program if you use an empty busy-wait loop and the forms of main() allowed by C++ in a freestanding environment.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Unfortunately our class want us to use atollic and without the abstraction layer that is HAL. They want us to learn to use register and code by using the reference manual to learn in a more intimate way the stm32. And since cubeIDE make it easy to avoid using all the documentation, they want us to avoid it. Example, if I wanted to see what pin is connected to the internal peripheral of, let's say, the TIMER 2 DAC, I could simply go over the DAC and see the pin number; Therefore , bypassing the use of the reference manual. Although, I will use cubeIDE for my midterm project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following applies to both C and C++. All of the following code is compilable as both C and C++.

> why does this `main` function with an incrementing integer never overflow?

It does overflow. Since the integer is signed, however, it is *undefined behavior* and a bug. Depending on the compiler and hardware architecture the code is being compiled for, the compiler may handle signed integer overflow and underflow in expected ways, ex: wrapping around to the minimum value on overflow, but it's not a guarantee, not allowed per the language standards, and not a good idea.

See the quotes in this question: [Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195715/4561887) (emphasis added):

> Unsigned integer overflow is well defined by both the C and C++ standards.  For example, the [C99 standard][http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf] (`§6.2.5/9`) states
>
> > A computation involving **unsigned operands can never overﬂow,**
> > because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
> > reduced **modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value** that can be
> > represented by the resulting type.
>
> However, both standards state that signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.  Again, from the C99 standard (`§3.4.3/1`)
>
> > An example of **undeﬁned behavior is** the behavior on **integer overﬂow**

Next question:

> Also, is it safe to use the same tactic (using `while(1) i++`) to loop around while waiting for a specific interrupt?

Using the following is just fine in a microcontroller, yes:

```c
int main(void) 
{
    while (1) 
    {
        // loop continually as fast as the processor can, while waiting for 
        // interrupts; ISR (interrupt service routine) function definitions not
        // shown 
    }

    // On a microcontroller, this code must never be reached!
    return 0;
}
```

On any system with an operating system, however, you should sleep in the while loop, even if only for a millisecond, to give the scheduler a chance to run other processes. On bare-metal (meaning: having no operating system) microcontrollers, however, the infinite while loop running as fast as it can is normal.

---

You must *not* rely on undefined behavior signed integer overflow and underflow. Instead, rely on *well-defined behavior* unsigned integer overflow and underflow.

This is perfectly fine:

```c
#include <stdint.h>  // for uint16_t, etc.

int main(void) 
{
    uint16_t counter = 0;
    while (1) 
    {
        counter++; // increment unsigned counter; overflow is fine

        // use the `counter` variable somewhere or else it may be optimized out
        // completely by the compiler

        // loop continually as fast as the processor can, while waiting for 
        // interrupts; ISR (interrupt service routine) function definitions not
        // shown 
    }

    // On a microcontroller, this code must never be reached!
    return 0;
}
```

With unsigned integers, things like this are also perfectly fine. Note that `uint8_t` is an unsigned 8-bit integer, with values ranging from 0 to 255:

```c
uint8_t u1 = 0 - 1;  // underflows to 255 at compile-time

uint8_t u2 = 0; 
u2 - 1;  // underflows to 255; can be at run-time

uint8_t u2 = 255;
u2 + 1; // overflows to 0; can be at run-time

uint8_t u3 = 255;
u3 + 2; // overflows to 1; can be at run-time

uint8_t timestamp_end = 128;
uint8_t timestamp_beginning = 129;
// The result is 255
uint8_t time_difference = timestamp_end - timestamp_beginning; 

timestamp_end = 100;
timestamp_beginning = 200;
// The result is 156
time_difference = timestamp_end - timestamp_beginning;
```

### More on the infinite `while` loop in microcontrollers

As an example, below is the [`main()` C++ function for the AVR microcontroller cores in Arduino](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp) (think: ATmega328: Arduino Uno, Nano, etc).

Notice the infinite `for (;;)` loop. Using `for (;;)` is exactly identical to using `while (1)` or `while (true)`. Inside there, it calls the user-defined `loop()` function, calls `serialEventRun()` so long as that function is defined (see Note 1 below), then repeats, as fast as the processor can run! Everything else you write must be handled through interrupts processed in ISRs outside of the main loop, or through cooperative multi-tasking inside the main loop ([see some of my example code doing this in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50032992/4561887)), which is really quite effective.

Note 1: in the gcc compiler, `__attribute__((weak))` functions which are never defined are equal to zero, which would make `if (serialEventRun)` false. See my test code in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: [cpp/check_addr_of_weak_undefined_funcs.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/check_addr_of_weak_undefined_funcs.cpp). Example output is at the very bottom of that file.

The `serialEventRun()` function calls an optional, custom, user-defined `serialEvent()` function if it is defined. If the user doesn't define it, it's a weak empty function declared as `void serialEvent() __attribute__((weak));`. See my answer on this here: [Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67016917/4561887).

Also notice the `USBDevice.attach();` call. I haven't looked into it, but I suspect that attaches a callback to an ISR (interrupt service routine function), so that the callback function gets called whenever (apparently) a USB-related interrupt occurs.

Also notice that the user's `setup()` function gets called only once, prior to entering the infinite `for (;;)` loop, whereas the user's `loop()` function gets called repeatedly inside the infinite `for (;;)` loop:

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

// Declared weak in Arduino.h to allow user redefinitions.
int atexit(void (* /*func*/ )()) { return 0; }

// Weak empty variant initialization function.
// May be redefined by variant files.
void initVariant() __attribute__((weak));
void initVariant() { }

void setupUSB() __attribute__((weak));
void setupUSB() { }

int main(void)
{
    init();

    initVariant();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif
    
    setup();
    
    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

### Pedandic, language-lawyer-like note

From [@Eric Postpischil's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226293/in-c-and-c-why-does-this-main-function-with-an-incrementing-integer-never-o/77226496#comment136144981_77226293):

> C++ 2020 draft n4849 6.8.1 says, in a note,
>
> > Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow. Overflow for signed arithmetic yields undefined behavior (7.1).
>
> As used by the standards, signed integer arithmetic overflows, because a specified result (such as the sum for an addition) cannot be represented in the result type, and unsigned arithmetic never overflows, because operations are specified to wrap, so the specified result is always representable.

In other words, technically the word "overflow" means "cannot hold the specified result", and so only signed integers do this, but unsigned integers do not do this, because they are specified to wrap around, so their results are always representable.

That's backwards from how (virtually all) of us use those words. We use "overflow" to mean "wrap around", and so unsigned integers properly overflow, but signed integers do not. Again, *technically* we have these definitions backwards in our common vernacular, myself included, even in my answer above.

But, we aren't language lawyers here, so I will continue to say that unsigned integers have "well-defined" underflow and overflow, and signed integers have "undefined behavior" underflow and overflow.

### See also

1. It turns out I've answered a question like this before. See my answer here: [Adding int type to uint64_t c++: *Undefined behavior signed*-integer overflow/underflow, and *well-defined behavior unsigned*-integer overflow/underflow, in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73200042/4561887)

Comment: *"Most compilers"* It seems only MSVC does wraparound by default. GCC and Clang optimize on the assumption that it never overflows: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b8Pe91r41

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I updated my wording. I'd be interested in what the gcc-for-AVR-microcontrollers compiler does. I know in my past experiments it overflows and underflows signed integers for me in expected ways, but I also don't write any code outside of brief experiments with signed integer overflow on any system, period.

Comment: Godbolt has AVR GCC too, seems to use the same optimization: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6rcje7M5f There are flags (`-fwrapv` I think?) that disables this behavior, maybe it's used by default in the one you're using.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, interesting. When `x` is `int`, `return x < x + 1;` optimizes to `return 1` essentially, implying that `x + 1` is expected to _never_ overflow to the minimum (most negative) integer value. The result gets more complicated and no longer optimizes to this when you make it an `unsigned int`, meaning it properly handles overflow in the optimizations.

Comment: GitHub Copilot was very useful to understand the assembly. I simply asked, "Explain this godbolt x86-64 gcc 13.2 assembly: `foo(unsigned int):  cmp     edi, -3      setbe   al       ret`", but with the assembly code properly formatted.

Comment: Mhm, because unsigned overflow is legal, with the behavior described by the standard, while signed overflow is illegal.

Comment: Very educational, complete and erudite treatment on the topic, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think it does not overflow?
No runtime error is likely and nothing in the code detects an overflow.

Although it is "undefined" for signed integers, invariably, at least for in optimised code, what will happen will be architecture dependent, and the most likely result is 0x7FFF... (max positive) will "increment" naturally to 0x8000... (max negative).

If your `int` is 64 bit on your platform, it will in any event take a very long time before it overflows (i.e. not in your lifetime).

For optimised it is probable that the variable will be removed altogether since it serves no purpose being written but never read.

Comment: Wouldn't it wrap from `0x7FFF'  (max sint16) to 0x8000 (min sint16)? ..  0xFFFF = -1

Comment: @kesselhaus that is what I intended, corrected.  The ellipsis (...) were an attempt to indicate more repeated digits may apply depending on size of int, not to imply 16 bit

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the integer 'i' does overflow in your code, but there is nothing in your code that makes the overflow apparent/visible.

Here is my approach to this issue.  Using an unsigned int rather than signed is preferred, because behavior of an unsigned int which exceeds its max limit is defined by the C standard: it does a 'wraparound' to zero. Note that signed integer overflow behavior is Not defined by the standard, so we will avoid using a signed int.

It is perhaps improper to say that this code demonstrates "overflow," because per the C standard, unsigned ints do not overflow -- they wraparound when their limit is reached. This is arguably a problem only of semantics, because in the most basic sense, exceeding the limit of an integer and overflowing it are essentially the same animal; perhaps a distinction without a difference.

Please also see:  [C/C++ unsigned integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow)

Runnable version of this code here: https://godbolt.org/z/Kz6YonEhz

All that said, this demonstrates the defined behavior of incrementing an integer beyond its limit (and we avoid calling it 'overflow'):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t i = 1;

    while(i>0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    printf("i overflowed at: %u  sizeof(i): %u\n", i-1, sizeof(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No DV, but the OP's question relates to microcontrollers... returning from `main()` seems like a bad idea...

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but one issue with this answer is that it doesn’t actually answer the question that was asked (specifically, why his program doesn’t overflow, not that it’s entirely clear what he meant by that)

Comment: [Asking for reasons for downvotes as a comment is discouraged.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, which part of this is undefined behavior? I'm not following what you're saying exactly.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I misread the answer.