# Why x*x with uint16_t gives wrong result

Tags: c

Could someone explain why pow variable is set to -131071 (0xfffffffffffe0001) in this example?

```
uint16_t x = 0xFFFF;
uint64_t pow = x*x;
```

I know it can be fixed by casting x to uint64_t, but my question is why it gives wrong result without a cast.

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint16_t x = 0xFFFF;
    uint64_t pow = x*x;
    printf("%ld\n", pow);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because x*x overflows and the assign comes too late

Comment: Your operands are getting promoted to (signed) `int`s

Comment: `uint64_t pow = x*x;` ==> `uint64_t pow = (uint64_t)x*x;`

Comment: My answer here will help: [Integer and floating point rank and promotion rules in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654668/4561887).

Comment: Aside `printf("%ld\n", pow);` is the wrong format, use `printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", pow);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
uint16_t x = 0xFFFF;

// 1. wrong
uint64_t pow = x*x;

// 2. right
uint64_t pow = (uint64_t)x*x;
```

In 1, since `x` is a "small integer type" (see [@Lundin's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/4561887) and [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654668/4561887) for more on that, it first gets promoted to `int`, and then the multiplication is performed. This results in *undefined behavior* signed integer overflow, which is a bug.

In 2, we first cast `x` to `uint64_t`. Then, the multiplication is performed on two `uint64_t` values, which is well-defined whether it overflows or not (but it won't overflow in this case), and we get the correct result.

---

These types of "gotchas" are very tricky in C and C++, and cause a lot of people (myself included) a lot of frustration when trying to do math in C or C++. You have to study these gotchas and take care to do it correctly. A lousy, (temporary, or else your code bloats) work-around is to just use `double` for everything, which is what computation-intensive languages like MATLAB do. See: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types.html:

> By default, MATLAB® stores all numeric variables as double-precision floating-point values.

### See also

This topic comes up a lot, so, I'll link to a lot of other relevant answers on this topic here:

1. [Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195715/4561887)
2. [Integer and floating point rank and promotion rules in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/4561887)

   1. [@Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/4561887)
   2. [my summary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654668/4561887)

      From the bottom of my answer there:

      > 1. https://cppinsights.io/ - a very useful tool which expands your C++ code into exactly what the compiler sees, including after applying all automatic implicit type promotion rules in the compiler.
      >
      >    1. Ex: see my code above here: https://cppinsights.io/s/bfc425f6 --> then click the play button to convert and expand it into what the compiler sees.
3. My answer: [Adding int type to uint64_t c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73200042/4561887)
4. My answer: [In C , why does this `main` function with an incrementing integer never crash from overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77226496/4561887)
5. My answer: [How could I safely find the absolute difference between 2 signed integers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76420269/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

**Narrower `int`?**

As an `int/unsigned` may be as narrow as 16-bits<sup>*1</sup>, instead of the common 32-bits, for fun, let us look at what happens with a 16-bit `int/unsigned` and 32-bit `int/unsigned long`.

---

`0xFFFF` is a integer constant of type `unsigned`, the same width as `uint16_t`.

```
uint16_t x = 0xFFFF;
```

---

In the expression `x*x`, each `x` is promoted to `unsigned`.  (Likely `uint16_t` is already an `unsigned`.)  Then the multiplication of two `unsigned` form an `unsigned` product.  Since the product is outside the range of `unsigned`, it is reduced to modulo `UINT_MAX+1`.  0xFFFF * 0xFFFF --> 0xFFFE0001 reduces to 0x0001.  Then `pow` is assigned the value of 1.

```
uint64_t pow = x*x;
```

---

`"%ld\n"` expects a matching `long` (in our case it is 32-bit), yet `pow` is a `uint64_t`. This results in *undefined behavior* (UB).  Don't do that.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77508925/why-xx-with-uint16-t-gives-wrong-result/77509473#comment136644001_77508925)

```
printf("%ld\n", pow);  // UB

// Better as
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", pow);
// Expected output: 1
```

---

A common migration is to insure that the math "on the right" uses at least the rank of the type "on the left".

```
uint64_t pow = (uint64_t)1 * x * x;
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> In 2023, common in many embedded processors.