# Is it undefined behaviour to read a different member than was written in a Union?

Tags: c++

```
union test{
  char a; // 1 byte
  int b;  // 4 bytes
};

int main(){ 
  test t;
  t.a = 5;
  return t.b;
}
```

This link says: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

> It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.

According to this, does my sample code above have UB?
If so then what's the point of a Union then? I thought the whole point it to read/write
different value types form the same memory location.

If I need to access the `most recently written` value then I will just use a
regular variable and not a Union.

Comment: the initial motivation for unions was to save memory when you only ever need one of the members at a time afaik. It was in the old days when you didnt have loads of memory.

Comment: A real life use-case for unions: we have an API that allows to query about a number of different parameters. These parameters can have different types (including classes). Because of this, we return a wrapper struct that contains an enum denoting active member and a union of possible parameter types, filled with correct data.

Comment: _If so then what's the point of a Union then?_ Employing union does not imply the need for reading its inactive members. For instance, see the implementation of `std::basic_string` in libstdc++, where a buffer for short strings is aliased with the capacity member variable. Since you can detect short/long strings by comparing the data pointer with the address of this buffer, there is no need for accessing an inactive member and union is still useful. Code: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L178.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning)

Comment: Also relevant: [Unions, aliasing and type-punning in practice: what works and what does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54762186/580083).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is definitely not just some _old-days-issue_. Unions are still used, e.g., in implementations of string classes in all mainstream libraries (libstdc++, libc++, Microsoft STL). You don't want string objects to be unnecessarily large, since there may be a lot of them in memory at once.

Comment: An alternative is to use a smart union, [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: Note that the comment in `int b; // 4 bytes` is often correct, but the C++ standard does not require it. `int` has to be at least 2 bytes, and it has to be at least as large as `short` (which also has to be at least 2 bytes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the behaviour is undefined in C++.

When you write a value to a member of union, think of that member becoming the *active member*.

The behaviour of reading any member of a union that is not the active member is undefined.

in C++, a `union` is often coupled with another variable that serves as a means of identifying the active member.

Comment: Importantly UB does not mean "crashes". Doing what OP thought it *should* until one day not is validly UB.

Comment: Does does apply in C too? or only C++?

Comment: C++ is stricter. In C you can indeed type pun through a `union`.

Comment: I see, so this is valid in C but not C++, is there a link which mentions it's valid in C?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning

Comment: Thanks, this makes Unions, well, mostly pointless.

Comment: It might be worth adding that some implementations (maybe most) support reading an inactive union member as a non-standard extension. (IIRC, for example, SSO implementation in libc++ relies on this.)

Comment: @Dan - Unions are not pointless in embedded systems where memory space may be severely restricted, which is why they exist. In your example the union is 4 bytes, whereas the two members separately would require 5.

Comment: @ChrisBD Two members separately would require 5, but putting them into `struct` or `class` would require 8 due to padding/alignment.

Comment: @ChrisBD Then you can use `bit fields` instead for saving memory.

Comment: @DanielLangr - correct, which is why I didn't mention structs

Comment: @Dan - I don't envy anyone trying to use bitfields instead of a union when handling floating point numbers. That's the beauty of unions they can "contain" anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your implication that having unions without the possibility of reading their inactive members makes them useless is wrong. Consider the following simplified implementation of a string class:

```
class string {
  char* data_;
  size_t size_;
  union {
    size_t capacity_;
    char buffer_[16];
  };

  string(const char* str) : size_(strlen(str)) {
    if (size_ < 16) 
      data_ = buffer_;  // short string, buffer_ will be active
    else {
      capacity_ = size_;  // long string, capacity_ is active
      data_ = new char[capacity_ + 1];
    }
    memcpy(data_, str, size_ + 1);      
  }

  bool is_short() const { return data_ == buffer_; }
  ...
public:
  size_t capacity() const { return is_short() ? 15 : capacity_; }
  const char* data() const { return data_; }
  ...
};
```

Here, if the stored string has less then 16 characters, it is stored in `buffer_` and `data_` points to it. Otherwise, `data_` points to a dynamically-allocated buffer.

Consequently, you can distinguish between both cases (short/long string) by comparing `data_` with `buffer_`. When the string is short, `buffer_` is active and you don't need to read `capacity_`, since you know it is 15. When the string is long, `capacity_` is active and you don't need to read `buffer_`, since it is unused.

Exactly this approach is used in libstdc++. It is a bit more complicated there since `std::string` is just a specialization of `std::basic_string` class template, but the idea is the same. Source code from `include/bits/basic_string.h`:

```
enum { _S_local_capacity = 15 / sizeof(_CharT) };

union
{
  _CharT    _M_local_buf[_S_local_capacity + 1];
  size_type _M_allocated_capacity;
};
```

It can save a lot of space if your program works with a lot of strings at once (consider, e.g., databases). Without union, each `string` objects would take 8 more bytes in memory.