# Type casting struct to short/int for saving value on adress

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to know, if its possible to cast struct to short but only 2 bites of its adress and save value in there. I personally dont even know if its possible just wanna get any ideas how to do that.

In my project i link void adress of char to struct and then doing something similar like malloc but without using malloc.. making somthing like function malloc.

My struct and its pointer:

```
    typedef struct mem_list {
    int size;
    struct mem_list *next;
    struct mem_list *prev;
}mem_list;

mem_list *start;
```

my function memory init:

```
void memory_init(void *ptr, unsigned int size){

    mem_list *temp;
    temp = (mem_list*)ptr;
    if(size <= sizeof(mem_list)){
        temp->size = 0;
        printf("Failed\n");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        temp->size = size - sizeof(mem_list);
        temp->next = NULL;
        *((unsigned short*)(&temp + size - sizeof(unsigned short))) = 0;
        start = temp;

        printf("Inicialized was %d bits\n",size-sizeof(mem_list));
        return;

    }
}
```

My main:

```
int main() {

    char region[100];

    memory_init(region, 60);

    //char* pointer = memory_alloc(20);

    //printf("adresa %d\n", pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is in function memory init in this part of code:

```
*((unsigned short*)(&temp + size - sizeof(unsigned short))) = 0;
```

**What i want to do is to move to end of my inicialized memory and save there short typed zero for showing me later where is end of my memory. And also would like to ask how can i acces that value later?** I know there maybe are mistakes in my code. Woul be happy if you point me where and give me some ideas how to do that. thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you just add an `unsigned short` to your `struct`? Also I would recommend not to use a `char` array and then cast its address to pointer of your `struct` - Why don't use `malloc` for allocating?

Comment: @oddysseus thats our project in school, we cannot use malloc we have to alloc memory manually. And to that short i want to add it to the end because it will sign me that its end when going trhough linked list through adresses

Comment: `&temp + size - sizeof(unsigned short)` fails as it is `mem_list *` math, not `char *` math.  Rest of code is troubling too.

Answer (score 2):

`(&temp + size - sizeof(unsigned short)))`: `&temp` is the address of the pointer to your `mem_list`, so `&temp + xxx` is the address of somewhere in the stack :-(

The address of the last byte of your `mem_list` object is `(char*)temp + size`.

---

To be cleaner you could define your

```
typedef struct mem_list {
    int size;
    struct mem_list *next;
    struct mem_list *prev;
    unsigned short  body[]
} mem_list_t ;
```

Then:

```
    blen  = (size + sizeof(unsigned short) - 1) / sizeof(unsigned short) ;
    temp->body[blen] = 0 ;
```

writes 0 to the last `unsigned short` of the body of the `mem_list_t`.

Note that this assumes that `ptr` points to an object which has been allocated with `asize` bytes:

```
    asize = offsetof(mem_list_t, body[blen+1]) ;
```

with `blen` calculated as above.  (And `ptr` needs to be aligned as required for `mem_list_t`, of course.)

Comment: thanks much, more clear to me now.  :) but can i also ask,how to save short or int value there ?

Comment: What you have written will _probably_ work... replacing `&temp` by `(char*)temp`.  I say _probably_ because most machines these days will allow unaligned reads/writes.  Technically, _C_ thinks that casting from `(char*)` to `(unsigned short*)` is Undefined [except where the `(char*)` value was originally `(unsigned short*)`].

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you can reuse a char buffer to create objects of other types in it(*), but you should at least care about alignment. Some processors require non char types to be correctly aligned, for example that:

- the address of an `int16_t` shall be even
- the address of an `int32_t` or larger shall be a multiple of 4

And even if some other processors do not enforce this rule, accessing mis-aligned data often adds a significant overhead. That is the reason for padding in structs.

So without more precautions, this line:

```
*((unsigned short*)(&temp + size - sizeof(unsigned short))) = 0;
```

could break because if `size` is odd, you are trying to write an `unsigned short` at an odd address.

---

(*) For more details, you can read that other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38515179/3545273) from mine, specialy the comments on my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608659/3545273)

Answer (score 0):

> if its possible to cast struct to short but only 2 bites of its adress and save value in there

No, it isn't possible. `*((unsigned short*)(&temp...)` invokes undefined behavior. It is a so-called "strict aliasing violation" and can also lead to misalignment issues depending on system. [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

The rule of thumb is: never wildly cast between completely different pointer types. You need a lot of detailed knowledge about C in order to so in a safe manner.

You can do "type punning" either by using a `union` between the struct and a `unsigned short` though. Please note that endianess is an issue to consider when doing so.

Other than that, you can safely `memcpy` the contents of a struct into an allocated `unsigned short` or vice versa. `memcpy` is excempt from pointer aliasing rules and will handle alignment safely.