# How to compile my version of Malloc in C?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, header-files

I'm currently coding my implementation of the `malloc()` function, so I'm compiling with the following flags: `-m64 -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -nostdlib -ggdb3`.

For the time being, I'm compiling as an executable and not as a shared library.

For my implementation I'm using the header files `stddef.h` `stdint.h` `unistd.h`, for the moment I need the syscall `sbrk()`. The problem is that on compilation I get the following error: `undefined reference to sbrk`.

I assume that `sbrk()` and more generally `unistd.h` are disabled if I compile with `-nostdlib` but **how can I compile without the *glibc* but with the system calls?**

Thanks in advance

P.S I really need to use `sbrk()` I can't use `mmap()`, don't encourage me to do it.

Comment: An interesting read here, it's not possible to write malloc() in standard C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515179/is-it-possible-to-write-a-conformant-implementation-of-malloc-in-c

Comment: @Bathsheba: Actually yes it is. There is no standard primitive bigger than `long long` so you can always provide an aligned allocation.

Comment: @Joshua "no standard primitive bigger than long long" --> `long double`, `complex long double`, `uintmax_t`, pointers to functions are candidate privatives bigger than `long long`.  It is the alignment needs at issue, not the size.  The alignment needs of `max_align_t` are the specified max for privatives.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Oh good; new enough C can use max_align_t then. (long double's alignment isn't any worse that long long but oh well).

Comment: @Joshua "long double's alignment isn't any worse that long long" --> that may be true on some machines, but it is not C specified to be that way. IAC, it is the alignment needs of `max_align_t` which solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing what it sounds like you are trying to do, then you will eventually have to write your own implementation of all of the C library functionality that you need.  However, a stepping stone in that direction is to compile your semi-freestanding program like this:

```
gcc -c -ffreestanding [other options] -o foo.o foo.c
# ... repeat the above for all other object files ...

gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostartfiles -static -o yourprogram \
    foo.o [other objects] -lc -lgcc
```

This tells the C implementation to supply *only* the parts of the standard libraries that you actually use yourself.  Note that many standard APIs will not work correctly in this mode; don't use anything from `stdio.h`, nor anything locale-dependent (as the C standard uses that term), nor anything to do with threads.  The system call wrappers should be fine, though, as should most of `string.h`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your explanation of the semi-freestanding environments. I had another idea too: to code a "system call" in NASM x64 calling sbrk() but I can't find it in this list:  https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/ is `sbrk()` a syscall or just a libc function? And if it is a syscall, is it possible to call it easily by putting the increment in RDI, the right code in RAX and SYSCALL.

Comment: `sbrk` is not a system call; the actual system call is `brk` and calling it correctly requires some finesse.  See https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/sbrk.c for how it's done.

Comment: In general you _can_ write your own system call wrappers (and in the end you will have to) but you have got to watch out for subtle differences between the documented API in the manpages, which is the behavior of the C library's wrappers, and the actual behavior of the kernel. More often than you might expect, the wrapper is doing more than just setting up the registers and issuing a `syscall` instruction. I do this kind of work with the C library source tree open in another window so I can check.

Comment: Ok... I didn't know that `sbrk()` wasn't a syscall, so that's why it didn't compile with `-nostdlib`, thanks for the source file, although I'm not sure I understand `extern void *__curbrk;` nor the principle of weak aliases.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in there you can ignore if you aren't trying to write a fully standard-compliant C library, such as everything to do with weak aliases, and all the names having a leading `__` for no apparent reason. `extern void *__curbrk;` just means that a variable named `__curbrk`, with type `void *`, is defined in a different file.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, don't use `-nostdlib`. `glibc` has special support for replacing `malloc()`

This should enable `sbrk()` to work. Don't start multiple threads or you will have a headache.

If you can't find `sbrk()`, call `mmap()` instead. `sbrk()` is obsolete and doesn't interact very well with modern system facilities.

Comment: Note that replacing malloc is not trivial; detailed instructions may be found at https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html

Comment: *`sbrk()` is obsolete and doesn't interact very well with modern system facilities.*  `sbrk()` is used by glibc's own `malloc()` implementation.  If the OP is replacing the entire `malloc()` implementation, `sbrk()` will work just fine.